# Usar tipo de variável não primitiva em C# pode afetar no desempenho?

Tags: c#, .net, tipagem, desempenho

Usar tipo de variável não primitiva em C# pode afetar no desempenho?

Já vi vários códigos em que, ao invés de ser utilizado tipos primitivos do C#, muitos utilizam tipos semelhantes ao de outras linguagens que a IDE aceita.

Já questionei um programador porquê ele fazia isso e ele me disse que era porque gostava da combinação de cores, hehe...

Por exemplo:

```
Primitivo  --> Utilizado
int        --> Int32;
string     --> String;
long       --> Int64;
```

Comment: Note que em C# não existe propriamente o conceito de variável primitiva. O que você está falando é apenas um *alias* do tipo real que é sempre um `object`, em alguns casos mais precisamente um tipo derivado de `struct` como por exemplo o `int` ou o `long`.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Qual é a diferença de string vs String?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3711/qual-%c3%a9-a-diferen%c3%a7a-de-string-vs-string)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Não, estes casos que você exemplificou, `int` -> `Int32`, por exemplo, não só não afetam o desempenho como não faz nenhuma diferença o uso de um ou outro.

`int` é apenas um apelido (alias em inglês) para `Int32`, assim como string é para String e long é para `Int64`.

Toda vez que você escreve `int`, o compilador traduz o código para para o tipo `System.Int32`.

Contudo vale manter um certo estilo na hora de escrever código, usar diferentes apelidos do tipo de dados apenas por "gostar da combinação de cores" não me parece muito sensato uma vez que dúvidas como a sua podem surgir para quem irá ler e manter o código.

Answer (score 6):

`int` é um alias para `System.Int32`, tal como `string` é para `System.String`.

Eles compilam o mesmo código, logo tecnicamente não haverá diferença de performance entre os dois.
Lista de alias do C#:

```
object:  System.Object
string:  System.String
bool:    System.Boolean
byte:    System.Byte
sbyte:   System.SByte
short:   System.Int16
ushort:  System.UInt16
int:     System.Int32
uint:    System.UInt32
long:    System.Int64
ulong:   System.UInt64
float:   System.Single
double:  System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char:    System.Char
```

Answer (score 2):

Como é possível ver [nessa resposta do SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care) a diferença entre os tipos `Int32` e `int`, o que nós podemos estender para `String` e `Int64`.

A única diferença é o **aumento na legibilidade** do código, no caso do `Int32` e `Int64`, permitindo que, quando for pertinente, o desenvolvedor que estiver realizando a manutenção no código, não precise se preocupar, já que ele já tem o tamanho assegurado.