# Qual é a diferença de string vs String?

Tags: c#, .net, string, tipagem, estilo-de-codificação

Gostaria de saber qual é a real diferença entre o `String` (s maiúsculo) e o `string` (s minúsculo).

Aparentemente os dois têm os mesmos objetivos, porém qual é "melhor" para ser utilizado?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3261/2360

Comment: Escolhe aquele que achares mais legivel. A comunidade tende a concordar com o uso de `string`.

Comment: Em outras linguagens geralmente String é um objeto complexo, e string é um nativo

Comment: Relacionada http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/usar-tipo-de-variavel-nao-primitiva-em-c-pode-afetar-no-desempenho

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Já foi dito que `string` é apenas um *alias* para o tipo `String`.

Para deixar claro, não há diferença em performance ou forma como o código é gerado. Há exatamente **zero diferença** no tratamento de ambas. Elas podem fazer as mesmas coisas, e todos os membros estão disponíveis em qualquer um deles, afinal assim se comporta um alias.

Diferenças úteis na utilização e escolha:

- `string` é apenas uma forma mais simples de usar o tipo `String` no C#, ou seja, `string` é a forma de "tipar" uma cadeia de caracteres no C# e `String` é um tipo do CLR. No C#, dependendo do contexto, é melhor usar uma ou outra forma. O tipo `String` presente no namespace `System` pode ser usado em qualquer linguagem que se utilize do CLR.
- `string` não pode ser usado com reflexão. `String` deve ser usado no lugar.
- `String` pode ser usado para criar outros *aliases*:

  ```
   using str = System.String;
   //...
   str s = "Foi usado outro alias para string.";
   // a variável 's' é do tipo System.String que é o mesmo que ser string
  ```

  Mas esse é apenas um exemplo, não há necessidade e não é recomendado usar em código real. Existe sim casos que um alias pode ser útil, mas esse apenas dificulta a leitura para quem não está acostumado com isso, sem trazer nenhum benefício.
- Há alguns locais que ocorre o oposto e criar um *alias* pode trazer mais legibilidade ao código.
- Em outros casos pode ser apenas estranho usar um ou outro e dificultar a leitura.
- Na verdade o tipo `String` deve ser usado como `System.String` ou onde exista um `using System`, enquanto que `string` pode ser usado em qualquer código que o compilador já entenderá.
- `String` pode ser usado como identificador válido. `string` é uma palavra reservada e não pode ser um identificador.
- Há uma diferença na forma como o *syntax highlight* apresenta ambos. Pois uma forma é **tipo** e a outra é **palavra chave**.
- Apesar da recomendação geral em usar `string` sempre que possível enquanto está programando em C#, há controvérsias no seu uso. Alguns alegam que `String` é preferencial para deixar claro, através do Pascal Case, que você está usando um [tipo de referência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_type)<sup>(en)</sup>.

  Mas não faz muito sentido porque `Int32` é [tipo de valor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_type)<sup>(en)</sup> e também usa PascalCase (ou lowerCamelCase). E ainda ele, apesar de ser tipo de referência, tem semântica de valor. Então mesmo que usasse a lógica de [Pascal Case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PascalCase) para tipo de referência, e [Camel Case](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) (ou (UpperCamelCase) para tipo de valor, pela semântica, que é o que importa, ele deveria ser Camel Case, ou seja, deveria começar com minúsculo mesmo.

  No [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) o estilo de *case* é usado para ajudar determinar outras características do identificador.
- É possível substituir o tipo oficial por outro seu com mesmo nome se fizer tudo corretamente. O *alias *apontará para esse novo tipo que tem o mesmo nome e é colocado da mesma forma. Se ele não for exatamente o mesmo nome (incluindo o *namespace*) aí ele só pode ser usado opcionalmente o que quase inviabiliza o uso real.

Importante lembrar que ele é um tipo como outro qualquer por referência com semântica por valor e algumas facilidades que o compilador dá. O mesmo vale se usar `String`.

Também vale lembrar que [não existe tipo primitivo em C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16589255/221800) ([outra referência](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530321/221800)). Isso existe só como conceito do CLR, mesmo assim não como algo fundamental.

Importante notar que tudo isso é válido para o C#, outras linguagens como Java, ou até mesmo VB.NET podem ter mais diferenças.

- [Documentação oficial do `string` dizendo que é um alias](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/reference-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [FAQ reafirmando sobre aliases de tipos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/csharpfaq/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-system-string?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- [`System.String`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-6.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente resposta. Acrescento apenas o fato de que é  recomendável que o programador use sempre a mesma representação e não fique alternando entre uma ou outra sem nenhum padrão por questões de legibilidade.

Answer (score 34):

No [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) não existe diferença, pois, `string` é apenas um atalho para `System.String`.

Veja a lista completa de `aliases`:

```
object:  System.Object
string:  System.String
bool:    System.Boolean
byte:    System.Byte
sbyte:   System.SByte
short:   System.Int16
ushort:  System.UInt16
int:     System.Int32
uint:    System.UInt32
long:    System.Int64
ulong:   System.UInt64
float:   System.Single
double:  System.Double
decimal: System.Decimal
char:    System.Char
```

Answer (score 10):

Como explicado pelo John Skeet no Stack Overflow em inglês [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/215422/1245766), há um caso no qual precisa usar o `alias` em vez do `System.<obj>`, quando está declarando explicitamente o tipo de um `enum`. Por exemplo:

```cs
public enum Foo : UInt32 {} // Inválido
public enum Bar : uint   {} // Válido
```

Answer (score 3):

`String` é do tipo `System.String` e você o encontrá em qualquer implementação de qualquer linguagem para .Net, é um tipo definido pelo .Net Framework.

Já a `string` é uma keyword da linguagem C# que aponta para o tipo `System.String`. O mesmo é válido entre para `Int32` e `int`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

`string` é um alias (atalho) para `System.String`. Então, tecnicamente, não há nenhuma diferença. É como [`int` vs. `System.Int32`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62503/c-int-or-int32-should-i-care).

Geralmente é recomendado o uso de `string`, sempre que você está se referindo a um objeto.

Por exemplo:

```
string place = "world";
```

Da mesma forma, geralmente é recomendado o uso de `String`, se você precisa se referir especificamente à classe.

Por exemplo:

```
string greet = String.Format("Hello {0}!", place);
```

Este é o estilo que a Microsoft tende a usar em [seus exemplos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.String.Format.aspx#Format1_Example).

Parece que a orientação nesta área pode ter mudado, como [StyleCop](https://github.com/StyleCop) agora reforça o uso das C#-specific aliases.

> [Tradução e adaptação desta bela explicação do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string/7077#7077).

Obs: Estava preparando esta resposta para [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/48235/afinal-qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-em-declarar-string-min%C3%BAsculo-e-string), mais ela estava duplicada desta, então resolvi compartilha-la aqui. :)