# O que é realmente o "runtime environment"?

Tags: .net, clr, runtime

Estudando um pouco sobre o ASP.NET 5 me deparei com uma coisa que não entendi muito bem. Pra usar ele é preciso instalar o KVM (K Version Manager) e o KPM (K Package Manager). O KVM é responsavel por gerenciar versões do KRE (K Runtime Environment). No Powerhsell ao usar

```
kvm list
```

Eu tenho uma resposta mais ou menos assim

```
Active Version     Runtime Architecture Location                    Alias
------ -------     ------- ------------ --------                    -----
       1.0.0-beta1 CLR     amd64        C:\Users\User\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-beta1 CLR     x86          C:\Users\User\.kre\packages default
       1.0.0-beta1 CoreCLR amd64        C:\Users\User\.kre\packages
       1.0.0-beta1 CoreCLR x86          C:\Users\User\.kre\packages
```

Pelo que eu entendi então esse KVM gerencia versões diferentes do CLR. Mas o fato é que até hoje eu não entendi muito bem o que é runtime. O meu entendimento do CLR hoje é bem por cima, eu entendo assim: ao desenvolver uma aplicação usando C# o compilador transforma o código numa linguagem intermediária chamada CIL (Common Intermediate Language) e então o CLR é responsável por interpretar esse código intermediário.

Dessa forma, apesar do código C# ser compilado, o CLR ainda tem que interpretar um código intermediário. Meu entendimento é que o "Runtime Environment" é o ambiente no qual o CLR interpreta esse código intermediário.

Não sei se é isso mesmo. Dessa forma, o que realmente é esse "Runtime Environment"? Como ele realmente funciona? E por que existem tantas versões diferentes agora?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) é o [*runtime environment*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_system). O R é justamente *runtime*. É a infraestrutura responsável pela execução do programa.

De uma certa forma podemos dizer que todo programa precisa de um sistema de *runtime*. Alguns precisam de bem pouco - caso de coisas bem simples escritas em *assembly* (sua melhor chance do *runtime* ser bem leve ou inexistente) e C, outros precisam de muito - casos de linguagens interpretadas.

O fato de você precisar pedir coisas para o sistema operacional (uma alocação de memória por exemplo) já exige um *runtime*. Ele nada mais é que um conjunto de códigos que permitem que o programa faça coisas básicas.

No caso do .NET o *runtime* não é nada trivial. Ele é responsável por:

- acomodar todo o código;
- fazer a compilação *Just in Time* (que é um pouco diferente de só interpretar o *bytecode* da CIL);
- cuidar da segurança;
- gerenciar a memória (GC);
- lidar com as exceções;
- fornecer reflexão;
- prover e controlar interoperabilidade entre suas linguagens e com código externo nativo, incluindo serviços do sistema operacional (memória, processos, acesso a recursos, etc.);
- tem uma parte da biblioteca padrão que é necessária para o funcionamento básico de qualquer aplicação;
- e ainda tem subsistemas que permitem o monitoramento e diagnóstico da aplicação (provavelmente esqueci de alguma coisa).

Então você já sabia de uma parte do que é o CLR.

Note que o CLR existe para uma plataforma específica. Ela é a plataforma do .NET. Por isso não precisamos (ou não precisávamos) nos preocupar em que plataforma vai rodar. Ele se preocupa por nós mas no nível mais baixo tem que existir algo específico.

Existem versões diferentes porque existem evoluções e necessidades diferentes. Antes o lema era ter uma coisa só que atendia tudo, agora parece que é melhor ter versões especializadas que atende melhor só o que precisa. Cada abordagem tem suas vantagens.

O .NET já tinha algumas versões do CLR mas você não precisava se preocupar com isto. Era selecionado o que melhor atendia. Para melhor otimização de recursos você precisa se preocupar, se quiser. Isto tem sido resolvido porque com a unificação do CLR [haverá um só .NET](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101).

Algumas informações sobre as variações podem ser obtidas nesse [blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-core/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Código fonte aberto do CoreCLR oficial](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) para você tentar entender tudo o que tem lá dentro :) Divirta-se.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).