# O que é um dump de memória?

Tags: c#, .net, memória, dump

- O que é um *dump* de memória?
- Como ele pode auxiliar na possível identificação de uma inconsistência no código?
- Como é realizada a análise?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Termo

O [*memory dump*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_dump) ou despejo de memória é uma reprodução de tudo o que está na memória em um determinado momento da execução do programa. Em geral isto é feito em um momento de erro.

O despejo normalmente trata da reprodução física da memória e é muito importante me linguagens de nível um pouco mais baixo (*Assembly*, C, C++, etc.) que tem acesso total à memória e pode produzir resultados inesperados.

## C#

Não vou entrar em detalhes porque no contexto do C# isto tem zero relevância a não ser que adapte o termo ou tenha uma necessidade muito específica.

Como o C# roda em ambiente gerenciado, isto costuma ser pouco relevante a não ser que esteja trabalhando com o desenvolvimento do ambiente onde as aplicações C# rodam (o [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101)) ou em alguns casos fazendo um compilador que tentar ter uma forma própria de alocação, mas mesmo isto tem limitações. A característica gerenciada da ambiente evita os erros de alocação errada de memória que é onde esta "ferramenta" se destaca.

É até difícil conseguir o despejo em C#, precisa de alguma função própria desenvolvida em outra linguagem ou a utilização de uma ferramenta externa. Então no contexto do C# não se preocupe com isto.

## Análise

Em outros contextos eles podem ser analisados manualmente ou, o mais comum, através de ferramentas específicas que tentam dar melhores informações do que está nesta reprodução, como o que tem disponível no [WinDBG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou junto ao [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/).

Eventualmente pode-se usar os dados para alimentar aplicações e fazer simulações. Em alguns casos usa-se para obter estatísticas.

## Despejo de dados

Se usar o termo de forma aproximada e considerar que ele é apenas um estado da memória gerenciada, ou seja, você ter todos os estados de todas variáveis ativas na aplicação naquele momento de forma mais clara e em alto nível, então pode entender assim, mas é um equívoco dar este nome.

Dá para fazer um utilitário de depuração que capture estas informações da aplicação e gere um arquivo ou outra forma com os dados existentes na aplicação. Mas note que isto não é o mesmo que analisar a memória, isto é uma análise de dados que estão na memória, tem uma melhor abstração aí.

A infraestrutura do .NET possui ferramentas para fazer a coleta e análise destes dados. Leia mais a respeito na [documentação sobre o assunto](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/misc/analyze-dotnet-framework-memory-issues?view=vs-2015&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).