# O que realmente é o DNX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, .net-core, clr, dnx

Faz bastante tempo perguntei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51281/o-que-%C3%A9-realmente-o-runtime-environment) o que é o *runtime environment*, em especial na plataforma .NET. Acontece que agora o .NET possui o DNX que é o ".NET Execution Enviroment". Na prática usamos o DNX para executar softwares desenvolvidos com a nova versão do .NET, tendo suporte a utilizar o CLR usual ou então o Core CLR.

Nesse ponto que está minha dúvida. Pelo que estou vendo existe uma diferença entre o *runtime environment* (no caso CLR ou Core CLR) e o *execution environment* (no caso o DNX). Me parece que o DNX serve só para escolher um *runtime environment* e de alguma forma conectar o software com o *runtime environment*, mas eu não estou entendendo muito bem se é isso e como isso funciona.

Nesse caso o que realmente é o DNX e qual é a real necessidade dele? Além disso, qual a relação dele com o *runtime environment*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Isto não é mais válido com a implantação do [CLI - Command Line Interface](http://bleedingnedge.com/2016/02/04/new-toolchain-dotnet-cli/)

Aos poucos toda tecnologia que surgiu à partir da abertura do código do .NET e da arquitetura mais modular vai se consolidando e chegando no ponto de ter tudo o que é necessário para usar em produção.

Você já deve saber que o CoreCLR substitui o .NET que é uma plataforma cheia de coisas para fazer as aplicações funcionarem. Mas se for ver bem o CLR é apenas um dos componentes do .NET. Então a CoreCLR não substitui por completo o .NET. Alguns componentes que cuidam da infraestrutura de funcionamento das aplicações desenvolvidas usando a CLR são necessários para iniciar a aplicação.

Lembre-se que no momento que você instala o .NET no computador, você praticamente cria um segundo sistema operacional rodando ali. Se for no diretório onde o .NET fica instalado possivelmente dentro do `C:\Windows` verá que tem algo bem complexo ali. Aquilo não é só a CLR. Tem o compilador, gerenciadores de ambiente responsáveis pelo controle de exceções, gerenciamento de memória, *threads*, processos, domínios, segurança do código, etc. Ele é o hospedeiro nativo que executado as aplicações gerenciadas.

Pois bem, o DNX é isto mas com uma filosofia diferente, mais modular e menos intrusiva no sistema operacional, como é o .NET. É um jeito mais convencional de chamar a aplicação gerenciada, ou seja, você chama o DNX que vai chamar o resto. No .NET isto é mais transparente. Muita gente acha que está executando um executável real quando executa uma aplicação .NET. Note que não estou dizendo que é um substituto exato.

A [definição oficial](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/dnx/overview.html?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) diz que ele é um [SDK](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_Development_Kit) específico para aplicações .NET.

A motivação principal dele existir é para hospedar aplicações ASP.NET, já que ele permite que a aplicação rodar sem depender de uma infraestrutura extra, como o IIS, por exemplo. Mas não se restringe a isto.

Acho que nem preciso dizer que uma das diferenças dele para o .NET é que ele foi feito para rodar em diversas plataformas e o .NET original continua sendo exclusivo do Windows. Pela sua filosofia deve ser até difícil portar .NET na forma atual para outras plataformas. E a Microsoft nem está interessada nisto. Fazer o mesmo sistema de carga do ambiente e da aplicação seria muito complicado em outras plataformas. Por isto o Mono e o Java não fazem isto.

Na resposta que eu dei (*linkada* na pergunta acima) eu dou mais detalhes sobre o fato de existir vários *hosts*, várias versões do CLR, algumas personalizadas. Como gerenciar tudo isto, como ter algo em comum que faça tudo isto funcionar? A resposta é o DNX. Obviamente existem outras formas de executar uma aplicação .NET sem o DNX. Ele é uma das formas de fazer isto.

Ele também ajuda atender demandas mais modernas. Ele lida de um jeito moderno com configurações, pacotes e atualizações. Ele pode gerenciar as dependências e você só puxa para um *deploy* o que realmente vai usar.

[image: Diagrama do DNX]

Retirado da [Wiki do DNX](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-structure).

Eu sei que esqueci de algumas coisas que ele faz, eu tento melhorar com o tempo. Se tiver algo específico que precise saber, que seja traduzido da documentação, deixe um comentário.

É bom ficar atento às novidades. [O DNX está sendo modificado](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/blob/master/Documentation/intro-to-cli.md).