# DNVM, DNX, e DNU para que servem?

Tags: asp.net, dnx

Com o `ASP.Net 5` acabou surgindo estes novos modelos.
Este novo modelo também nos fornece ferramentas de linha de comando para gerenciar a escolha da versão do .NET, pacotes de bibliotecas, e ambiente de execução fora do Visual Studio. 
Mas de fato o que realmente cada modelo faz? Quais é a necessidade e o papel de cada modelo?

Comment: Isto já responde? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/89140/101