# Motivo para existir diferentes versões do DNX dependendo do SO

Tags: .net, clr, asp.net-core, runtime, dnx

Há um tempo atrás perguntei [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/89140/o-que-realmente-%C3%A9-o-dnx) sobre o que realmente é o .NET Execution Environment (DNX). Após ler a resposta e a Wiki do DNX passei a entender o DNX como uma interface entre a máquina virtual na qual o código gerenciado executa e o Sistema Operacional.

Ou seja, passei a entender as coisas da seguinte forma: quando trabalhamos com .NET estamos trabalhando com código gerenciado que roda dentro de uma máquina virtual (que antigamente era só a CLR). Essa máquina virtual precisa de uma interface com o sistema operacional, um software responsável por inicializar um processo para hospedar a máquina virtual, inicializar a mesma, cuidar das dependências, etc. No novo .NET essa interface é o DNX, correto?

Acontece que o DNX possui várias versões. Por exemplo, se utilizarmos `dnvm upgrade -r coreclr` no Linux x64 obtemos um DNX nomeado como

```
dnx-coreclr-linux-x64-1.0.0-rc1-update1
```

Enquando que ao rodar o mesmo comando no Windows temos

```
dnx-coreclr-win-x64-1.0.0-rc1-update1
```

No caso percebemos que embora em ambos os casos estamos simplesmente requerendo o .NET Core RC1 Update 1, o que ganhamos como DNX depende:

- Da versão da CLR escolhida - isso está refletido no fato do DNX possuir em seu nome a versão da CLR 1.0.0-rc1-update1
- Do sistema operacional utilizado - o nome do DNX indica o sistema operacional claramente
- Da arquitetura do processador - o nome do DNX indica ser x86 ou x64 claramente também

Durante muito tempo me perguntei o porque disso: se há simplesmente um .NET Core e um .NET Full, por que existem diversas versões do DNX?

Com o entendimento que tenho agora do DNX passei a entender isso da seguinte forma: por ser uma interface entre a máquina virtual (CLR) e o Sistema Operacional, o DNX depende da máquina virtual escolhida (CLR ou CoreCLR, bem como sua versão) e depende também das especificações do Sistema Operacional no qual vai executar essa máquina virtual, para ser capaz de mediar corretamente entre a máquina virtual e o Sistema Operacional.

Essa é realmente a razão pela qual, embora a gente se refira ao .NET Core somente como .NET Core (ou seja, uma coisa só), existem diversas versões do DNX? E consequentemente, esse jeito de entender o DNX é o mais correto mesmo? Caso não seja por aí, qual a razão real para termos todas essas versões diferentes de DNX?

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, essa pergunta já tem bastante tempo mas permanece aberta e bem interessante para a comunidade.

Imagine o .NET como sendo um conjunto de interfaces. É um exemplo simplista mas funcional. Você, então, estaria programando acessando métodos, eventos e propriedades dessas interfaces.

A implementação concreta depende de cada contexto, ou seja, de cada sistema operacional.

Em linguagens nativas você precisa compilar sua aplicação para cada destino: 32 ou 64 bits (além das mudanças internas no código, obviamente). Também é necessário preparar sua aplicação de formas diferentes para rodar em Linux ou Windows.

Outros frameworks (como o java) fazem o mesmo, mas de forma mais oculta. No caso, quando você enxerga os pacotes está, basicamente, visualizando os conjuntos de implementações das "interfaces" que você usou enquanto programava.

Lógico que é um pouco mais complexo que isso, até porque nem tudo são interfaces. Mas a ideia é basicamente essa, de o seu código executar sobre uma camada de abstração, a qual transforma um monte de API nativas e diferentes (Linux de um jeito, Windows de outro, etc) em um conjunto padrão para você trabalhar de forma consistente.