# Quais são as principais diferenças entre VB.NET, VB6 e VBA?

Tags: vb.net, vba, visual-basic-6

Quais são as principais diferenças entre VB.NET, VB6 e VBA?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## [VB6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic)

VB6 é a sexta e última versão da linguagem Visual Basic da Microsoft. Que por sua vez é uma evolução visual (facilita a criação de telas) do [BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) que foi o produto que fez nascer a Microsoft e criou toda uma indústria a partir dos anos 70. O primeiro VB nasceu em 1991 e o VB6 foi lançado em 1998. Ele aos poucos começou ter alguma forma de orientação a objeto bem rudimentar e falha.

## [VBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications)

Visual Basic for Applications é uma variação do VB6 que começou ser incorporado em produtos da Microsoft e licenciado para terceiros usarem em suas aplicações como forma de estendê-las e permitir a criação de *scripts*. Tem alguma limitação, mas também tem algumas possibilidades específicas para facilitar a integração com os produtos que a hospedam.

Ambos são considerados obsoletos, não suportados e hoje são altamente inseguros. Ainda que muita gente ainda use, isso é um erro grave, nem vale à pena falar de detalhes de tecnologias obsoletas e isso é o mais importante que deve se saber sobre elas. No caso do VBA a recomendação é usar [Visual Studio Tools for Applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Applications).

## [VB.NET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)

O VB.NET seria a evolução do VB para rodar em cima do .NET. Mas a linguagem é tão diferente que mal dá para chamar de evolução. Houve um esforço em dar compatibilidade para as aplicações antigas do VB6, mas muita coisa não funciona igual. Na verdade nem deveria tentar usar o jeito antigo de programar.

Com o tempo o VB.NET foi se aproximando mais do C# e abandonando de vez o estilo VB. Apesar de ainda evoluir e suportar, a Microsoft não fez um bom trabalho tentando manter em bom nível e cada vez tem menos programadores usando a linguagem, preferindo o C#. Há bem poucas vantagens da linguagem em relação ao C# e muitas desvantagens.

É possível haver integração de qualquer linguagem do .NET com outros produtos. A Microsoft hoje o adota como principal ferramenta para ampliar a flexibilidade das sua aplicações.

VB.NET é verdadeiramente orientado
a a objeto, possui um *runtime* ([o CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101)) bem melhor, muito mais rápido, até em função do [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), e possui um coletor de lixo mais moderno baseado em gerações, evitando os problemas da contagem de referência que havia no VB. Além disso há diferenças sintáticas e a biblioteca padrão é bem diferente, baseado em tudo o que foi feito para o C#. Há uma biblioteca extra para tentar manter compatibilidade. Tem algumas opções para usar um estilo mais que o outro.

Há um [artigo na Wikipédia com uma comparação](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Visual_Basic_and_Visual_Basic_.NET). Acho que fica mais a título de curiosidade, a não ser para quem está pensando em abandonar o VB6 e quer saber o que mudará. Embora eu ache que se vai começar algo novo, melhor ir de C#. A transição é quase a mesma para ir para o VB.NET e participará de uma comunidade mais ativa.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não entendo como o VBA pode ser obsoleto, sendo que é lançado melhor e mais revisado a cada nova versão do Office.

Comment: Pode ler o que está no *link*. Ele ainda existe, mas é obsoleto. A recomendação é usar o https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Tools_for_Applications

Comment: @taiar Correto. VBA Continua a ser suportado e com novidades: https://dev.office.com/blogs/VBA-improvements-in-Office-2016. Visual Studio Tools for Applications é de fato outro assunto, não atende todos os cenários que o VBA atende.

Comment: VBA é mesmo bem obsoleto. Mas eu d.u.v.i.d.o. a Microsoft um dia tirar ele (ela?) do ar com o tanto de gente que usa. rs

Comment: @LuizVieira E tem mais e mais código saindo a cada dia. O problema é que, embora VBA seja uma linguagem fraquinha, Excel + VBA é uma combinação muito poderosa, e a MS não oferece ainda nada a altura para substituir o VBA. Não entendi muito bem o "obsoleto" já que suporte e novidades permanecem.

Comment: @Caffé A obsolescência talvez seja mais no sentido de ele ter uma sintaxe antiga e um tanto "verborrágica" (`on error resume next`, pra mim, é o exemplo máximo disso rs), não no seu uso ou recursos.

Comment: Não tiraram nem VBScript do Windows até hoje... em falar nisso, a questão devia ainda mencionar VBScript. OP está discriminando! =D

Comment: @MiguelAngelo não vão tirar mesmo, a MS sempre manteve o compromisso com os produtos, mesmo os ruins :) É até um ponto positivo pra não deixar as pessoas na mão.

Comment: Eu até acho VBScript legal, tenho um monte deles por aqui... Eu ia ficar pra baixo se eles tirassem... =( rs

Comment: @MiguelAngelo eu tinha alguns, agora só PS.