# Pode se usar C++ e C# usando programação C?

Tags: c#, c, c++

Se eu montar um código pra um sotfware e nesse código querer usar as linguagens C, C++ e C# poderia? Mesmo que eu use um compilador que leia as três?

Comment: C e C++ "pode" , C# é outra história...

Comment: C# é um dialeto C mas é gerenciado (usa o framework .NET). Voce nao vai encontrar um compildador que compile C++ e C# pois, internamente, sao coisas bem diferentes. Lembre-se que existem diversos dialetos C, inclusive JAVA é baseado em C. C# pode ser comparado ao JAVA  (em termos que os dois sao gerenciados e geram um IL)  mas nao ao C++.

Comment: Você pode chamar coisas feitas em C / C++ dentro do C#, mas aí ja é _Unmanaged code_, não é portátil e tem uma série de consequências. Mais facil você explicar melhor do que precisa, para aumentar a precisão de possíveis respostas. Em outras palavras, dá pra misturar as tres coisas, mas é raro alguém precisar disso de verdade.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade C# não é um dialeto do C. Java então passa bem mais longe. Essa informação é bem errada. Se a pergunta tiver mais detalhes, como disse o Bacco, eu posso ainda melhorar a resposta

Comment: @bigown O que voce considera um dialeto? C# tem sim suas raizes no C++ assim como o Java tem suas raizes no C++ também.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade Dialeto é uma pequena variação da linguagem. C# é completamente diferente de C. Foi adotada uma pequenas características de sintaxe iguais e fica nisto. Dentro do que está falando quase todas linguagens e todo mundo chamam elas de linguagens, e não de dialetos, seriam dialetos de C porque possuem uma ou outra característica de C. nem C++ é dialeto de C, é quase um *superset*. C# tentou aproveitar algumas pequenas coisas do C++. Java passou longe, deliberadamente eu escolheram não seguir este caminho. Vai ficar longo demais para apenas comentar tudo.

Comment: @bigown Eu considero como dialeto aquelas linguagens que possuem uma mesma base sintatica. Ver a lista de linguagens que fazem parte da familia-C: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_C-family_programming_languages

Comment: Aí tudo seria dialeto, você considerar e ser de fato são coisas distintas. Ser da mesma família está longe de ser do mesmo dialeto. Português BR ou PT são dialetos. Português, Espanhol, Francês, Italiano, Romeno são da mesma família. Acha que nem família é, deve ser um nível acima, mas não sou linguista. Note que não tem uma definição do que é uma família de linguagens de programação, isso é algo que alguém escreveu, mas formalmente desconheço essa taxonomia e os critérios dela. Acredito que seja ter chaves e ponto e vírgula. Só isso!. Isto é muito pouco pra por tudo na mesma cesta.

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade leia o cabeçalho dizendo que muita gente considera aquilo errado.

Comment: @bigown Realmente adicionar PHP como um membro da familia C é forçar a barra, mas pelo menos voce concorda que sintaticamente que  JAVA e C# utilizam a sintaxe definida no C?

Comment: @WilliamJohnAdamTrindade muito pouco.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nenhum compilador lê as três, mesmo os que trabalham com C e C++, ou compilam C ou compilam C++.

Se estiver compilando C++, quase tudo que fizer com sintaxe de C funcionará porque a linguagem foi especificada assim. Mas nem sempre é o ideal.

O que dá para fazer é usar 3 compiladores e *linkar* tudo junto. No caso do C#, no momento o *linking* da parte em C ou C++ só poderá ser feito dinamicamente. Mas isso deve mudar em breve (aconteceu com limitações).

Chamar código C em C# é relativamente fácil. C++ não é. Em geral precisa fazer uma camada de "cola" entre o C++ nativo, com C#. Isto é escrito em C++/CLI que é um C++ gerenciado que roda em cima do [CLR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101). O que fizer em C# só poderia ser chamado pelo C++ nativo através desta cola. Até pode ser possível fazer sem esta cola, não é simples, não compensa, e só em alguns casos.

Chamar código C# pelo C só dá em casos bem específicos onde o código do C# foi escrito pensando em fornecer esta capacidade. Mas isso está melhorando.

Chamar código C em C++ costuma ser ok em quase todas situações. O contrário não é verdadeiro. E quase sempre não será tão simples. Se não fizer direito não fica bom. Mas funciona.

Evite fazer essas integrações tanto quanto der. Se tiver opção, não faça.