# O que é código gerenciado?

Tags: memória, runtime, clr, máquina-virtual

Em uma conversa com um colega de trabalho a respeito de qual linguagem foi usada para desenvolver o Windows, ele falou que muitas partes deveriam ainda estar desenvolvidas em C e C++, pois era preciso rodar código não gerenciado. Outras partes já estão desenvolvidas em C#. Daí surgiu a dúvida: o que diferencia código gerenciado de não gerenciado e qual a aplicação de cada um deles?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Windows essencialmente é desenvolvido com C e boa parte das APIs mais novas são em C++, com alguma compatibilidade com C. Não tem nada importante no Windows que use o .NET, ele pode ser completamente desinstalado. É um mito achar que a Microsoft está desenvolvendo quase tudo em C#. Ela faz o que tem sentido pra ela.

O .NET é uma plataforma que a Microsoft criou para dar mais segurança e flexibilidade no desenvolvimento de software. Até tinha a intenção de tudo passar para o .NET, mas se mostrou inviável. O .NET é uma implementação de várias tecnologias, entre elas o [*runtime* chamado de Common Language Runtime](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101). Esse *runtime* gerencia a execução, as permissões de execução, e a memória usada. Por mais que o programador queira fazer no seu código coisas inseguras e/ou problemáticas, a plataforma não deixa, tudo tem que passar por ela e ela gerencia o que é possível fazer, por isso é chamado de código gerenciado.

A forma mais óbvia de gerenciamento é o *garbage collector* que controla todas alocações e liberações de memória, ele toma pra si o gerenciamento da memória.

É possível ter implementações que só contem com gerenciamento do GC. Então, estritamente, o código gerenciado é aquele que se utiliza do GC para cuidar da memória, enquanto que o não gerenciado permite fazer o que desejar com a memória.

Algumas pessoas podem pensar em outras coisas, mas você ainda tem um código gerenciado mesmo se for nativo, mesmo que não tenha um [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101), um [CAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Access_Security), e demais tecnologias.

Note que o .NET é muito importante para a Microsoft e muita coisa de aplicação está sendo feita para você usar, mas nada no *core* do sistema operacional. Inclusive agora eles até desassociaram o .NET do SO.

Relacionado: [O que é marshalling e como funciona?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192342/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).