# O que é marshalling e como funciona?

Tags: .net, terminologia, marshalling

Estive trabalhando com um aparelho que enviava para o meu *software* algumas informações, porém essas informações eram vindas no tipo `IntPtr`, para lê-las, eu tive que usar a classe `Marshal` do .NET.

O que é *marshalling* e o que acontece quando converto um `IntPtr` para `String` usando a classe `Marshal`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Marshalling* é parecido com serialização, é uma técnica de transformar um objeto binário adequado para a memória em um objeto em formato adequado para transporte entre processos, possivelmente em máquinas diferentes.

Especialmente no .NET é usado para comunicação com [COM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) que é a base de muita coisa no Windows. Também é muito usado quando usa [código não gerenciado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192026/101) em geral (chamado de nativo, embora o termo seja *misleading*). Outro exemplo é [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).

Há um tratamento especial para ponteiros que obviamente não podem ser copiados diretamente, é preciso indicar que é uma referência para outro objeto que já pode existir onde será recebido ou precisa enviar também.

Mas de maneira geral a forma como o objeto é convertido depende de implementação. Pode ser que seja serializado mesmo, mas pode usar algum formato específico e protocolos da tecnologia usada, como o exigido pelo COM, por exemplo. O código não gerenciado possui diversos tipos próprios que não existem no .NET. Através do *marshalling* é possível acessar os dados na lado gerenciado de forma consistente.

> o que acontece quando converto um `IntPtr` para `String` usando a classe `Marshal`?

Não é que você transforma um [`IntPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) em `String`, você pode transformar um objeto "nativo" que se encaixa bem com uma *string* nesse tipo do .NET, o `IntPtr` é o indicador de onde está esta suposta *string* e provavelmente é ele que servirá de referência para a *string* e que será armazenado em uma variável como se fosse uma *string* gerenciada. Note que nenhuma conversão é necessária, apenas se atende os protocolos. É por isso, por exemplo que o `String` do .NET termina com um nulo mesmo tendo o tamanho do texto disponível logo no começo do objeto, é uma questão de interoperabilidade direta sem conversões já que o C só entende o [terminador nulo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101).

Dá para perceber muito disso que estou falando na classe [`Marshall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0). E também que ela não é nada simples e é preciso bom domínio de programação, funcionamento do sistema operacional, código nativo, etc. Mas praticamente ninguém precisa usar isto. É como o [`unsafe`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/142034/101), é bom ter, mas é pra uso bem restrito, o que aliás é comum `Marshal` trabalhar com `unsafe`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).