# Como diferentes linguagens de programação se comunicam?

Tags: python, c, c++, api

Uma dúvida que sempre tive e que me traz curiosidade é como diferentes linguagens de programação se comunicam entre si.

Não é tão raro ver diferentes projetos que usam linguagens diferentes em um mesmo software, como por exemplo um jogo utilizou as tecnologias de *C/C++* com *Python* ou algo do tipo.

Existe um API que faz essa comunicação entre linguagens? Gostaria de saber mais.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, existe uma API de comunicação, pelo menos nas linguagens mais abstratas como Python. As mais concretas em geral só se conformam com a linguagem mais universal.

Toda linguagem que se preze é capaz de chamar C, seja de forma natural através da [ABI](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/187944/101) ou de uma API criada para fazer a conversão de dados de forma a garantir a comunicação. C++ mesmo se comunica com C por ABI. C# tem um misto de ABI [e API](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/449300/101). ABI é mais eficiente que a API.

Linguagens de *script* podem um modelo de memória muito diferente e precisa de funções que pegam os parâmetros de forma diferente das linguagens mais nativas (quase sempre só usa-se C - ou C++/Rust de forma compatível com C). E para retornar o resultado também precisa de alguma conversão. Também de cuidar da forma de gerenciar as alocações de memória que são bem diferentes.

Geralmente isto é chamado de [Foreign Function Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) ou FFI. Em Python tem [documentação](https://cffi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) sobre (não achei na oficial). [Leia mais](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html).

[Em Lua](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/) é bem mais fácil entender a API para conversar com C, por ser mais simples, mas com mesmo poder.

Softwares específicos podem ter APIs específicas de comunicação.

Além disso é possível se comunicar sem usar ABI ou API. Por exemplo, com técnicas de RPC ou [IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication). Em geral são extremamente ineficientes, mas hoje muita gente não liga para isso, chega, até fazer um [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) via web. Em geral pode ser feito até mesmo sem conhecimento do que está do outro lado. É mais flexível, apesar da ineficiência. Em geral o pessoal evita até ser muito necessário.

[Veja mais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/134596/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Maniero! Nunca tinha ouvido falar de ABI até agora. Vou me aprofundar no assunto.

Comment: Gostaria de acrescentar que em sistemas que se utilizam de múltiplas linguagens muitas vezes tem módulos específicos onde, por exemplo, o módulo desenvolvido em C coleta dados e salva em um `banco de dados`, já o módulo desenvolvido em Python analisa os dados que estão no banco de dados. Outra possibilidade é que os módulos (ou micro serviços dependendo do "tamanho") se comuniquem por meio de um sistema de mensagens como RabidMQ, Kafka ou outro. Estes tipos de arquitetura são agnósticos à linguagem, ou seja os módulos/micro serviços poderiam até ter sido desenvolvidos na mesma linguagem.