# Qual é a diferença, na prática, entre "" e String.Empty?

Tags: c#, .net, string, vb.net

No .NET são perceptíveis as múltiplas formas de inicializar uma string com um valor vazio, vulgo "aspas aspas".

Existe uma forma correta de fazer isso? E qual seria a diferença prática entre usar:

- `var nome = String.Empty;`
- `var nome = "";`

Sei também que ainda tem o `string` e `String` no C#, porém foi visto [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/3787/41056) que não há diferença no uso dos dois.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Zero diferença prática. `string.Empty` equivale à `""`.

[No passado até houve alguma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151481/221800), então algumas pessoas recomendavam usar a "constante" e não o literal, mas hoje cada um usa o que achar mais legível e eventualmente for compactuado com a equipe

Eu uso `""`, até porque em alguns lugares a "constante" não pode ser usada (porque tecnicamente não é uma constante e sim um campo `readonly`). Isso vale para `switch-case`, *default argument*, atributos e qualquer outro local que exija uma constante que deve ser resolvida totalmente em tempo de compilação.

Se está preocupado com performance, há um [*benchmark* no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1588678/221800) com comparações de código IL e *Assembly*.

[Mais informações podem ser obtidas no código fonte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,69). E no [.NET Core](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,8281103e6f23cb5c).

A [documentação explicitamente diz que é a mesma coisa](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.empty?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

Por causa do [*interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) não há criação de uma nova instância em nenhum dos dois casos. Há apenas uma instância de *string* vazia alocada na área estática da aplicação e todas variáveis que têm esse valor apontam para a mesma instância (a fonte é uma [resposta no SO do Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263257/221800)). Ele usa o [padrão Flyweight](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Não tenho certeza disso, mas talvez o tipo `string` em C# também seja um objeto. Aí, nesse caso, `string.Empty` seria uma instância predefinida de uma string vazia, e por isso sua atribuição a uma nova string simplesmente faz uma cópia dessa instância. Enquanto que `""` na verdade é de fato uma string vazia, e sua atribuição literalmente constrói a uma nova instância a partir desse "valor vazio" (como se ele fosse "recebido como parâmetro" no construtor). Achei que valia esse (possível) detalhamento, ainda que você tenha toda razão: zero diferença prática. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira atualizei mostrando que isso não ocorre na prática.

Comment: Muito bom a parte sobre o *interning*. Eu não sabia. :)

Answer (score 14):

Não há realmente nenhuma diferença do ponto de vista de desempenho e código gerado. Em testes de desempenho, eles foram lá e cá, entre os quais um era mais rápido contra o outro, e só por milissegundos.

Em olhar o por trás do código, você realmente não vê nenhuma diferença também. A única diferença está no `IL`, que `string.Empty` usar o código de operação `ldsfld` e `""` usa o código de operação `ldstr`, mas isso é só porque `string.Empty` é estático, e ambas as instruções fazer a mesma coisa.

Se você olhar para o conjunto do que é produzido, é exatamente o mesmo.

Uma diferença é que se você usar na sintaxe de um `switch-case`, você não pode escrever `case string.Empty:` porque não é uma constante e você terá um `Compilation error : A constant value is expected`.

Como no exemplo abaixo.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string teste = "";

        switch (teste)
        {
             case "":
                Console.WriteLine("Case 1");
                break;
            case String.Empty:
                Console.WriteLine("Case 2");
                break;
        }           

    }
}
```

> Compilation error (line 14, col 9): A constant value is expected

Então user o que você achar mais legível, no entanto. É subjetiva e varia de pessoa para pessoa - então eu sugiro que você descubra o que a maioria das pessoas em sua equipe usar, e que todos façam a consistência.

Pessoalmente acho `String.Empty` mais fácil de ler.