# O que é Flyweight pattern?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, gerenciamento-de-memória, imutabilidade, flyweight

Pesquisando um pouco para entender melhor a lógica que leva [*strings* em Java a serem imutáveis](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164729/100), eu descobri que ["internação" de Strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) é um exemplo do padrão [*Flyweight*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight).

Conforme [o artigo da Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight) esse padrão pode ser utilizado para reduzir o consumo de memória, porém não ficou muito claro para mim o que esse padrão faz e como ele é implementado. Seria o padrão uma espécie de *cache* de valores?

O que é o *Flyweight pattern*? Quando devemos utilizá-lo e quais seriam bons exemplos de uso dessa técnica além de [*string interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## Economia de memória

Ele é uma forma de *cache* sim, mas está mais para compartilhamento.

É sempre útil quando você precisa ter várias instâncias de um objeto que possuem basicamente o mesmo valor. Isso obviamente faz mais sentido quando esses objetos são relativamente grandes ou quando há um compartilhamento de grande quantidade deles.

É claro que o *cache* (por [*Memoization*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) ou algo parecido) normalmente tenta evitar que um processamento já ocorrido tenha que ocorrer novamente. A economia de memória pode ocorrer, mas é possível também ocorrer o oposto, e.g., manter coisas em memória que sequer são usadas.

O *Flyweight* tem mais a intenção de economizar memória.

##### Performance

Em alguns casos mais raros, dependendo da implementação, é também possível usar memória para algo que não seja necessário.

Pode haver um ganho no processamento por não serem criados tantos objetos, mas nada expressivo. A economia se dá na criação e não no uso, que tende existir em proporção maior que a criação.

Pode até haver alguma perda criando-se algo desnecessário.

E pode haver ganho por otimizar o uso da memória e evitar coletas de lixo, *swap* e perda de [localidade de referência](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

#### Quase um Singleton

Ele lembra um pouco o [*Singleton*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), mas não precisa ter uma só instância, pode ter vários objetos se eles forem diferentes. O *Singleton* tem um objeto de um determinado tipo que é compartilhado por toda aplicação. O *Flyweight* tem tantos objetos quantos forem necessários, mas cada objeto idêntico - mesmo tipo e mesmo valor - é compartilhado.

Então podemos dizer que ele é útil também para manter uma forma canônica do objeto.

#### Imutabilidade e identidade

Note que o *string interning* possui limitações, ele ocorre apenas em objetos definidos em tempo de compilação. Duas *strings* idênticas criadas em tempo de execução não serão internalizadas, ao menos não de maneira automática (veja [`String.intern()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html) e [`string.Intern()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.intern?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0#System_String_Intern_System_String_)).

Assim como as *strings*, qualquer um desses objetos costumam ser imutáveis, até porque se mudar algo neles, os mesmos passam a ter [outra identidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101). Tendo outros valores internos, é outro objeto; esse objeto mudado não pode mais ser compartilhado com os outros que mantiveram seus valores.

Existem muitos casos em que parte do objeto pode ser compartilhado e parte precisa de algo personalizado. Então pode ser usado um mecanismo para juntar as duas coisas. Eles falam muito em estado compartilhado (*intrinsic*) e estado não compartilhado (*extrinsic*). Se não houvesse esse tipo de separação alguns objetos teriam sempre uma identidade diferente e não poderiam ser compartilhados.

Curiosamente esse é mais um dos padrões que desmontam um pouco o jeito OOP de fazer as coisas, pelo menos em alguns cenários específicos. Em vez de herança, usa-se composição. A herança possivelmente teria uma parte herdada que não muda em todos os objetos, com a composição do *Flyweight* essa parte pode ser compartilhada.

Como boa parte dos padrões de projeto, ele costuma ser usado em conjunto com outros padrões.

## Exemplos

#### Jogos

Ele é muito usado em jogos. Não sei se usaram, mas pense no [Age of Empires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Empires) que pode ter 200 unidades de batalha por civilização. Em computadores antigos ele ficava lento. Já o [Cossacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cossacks:_European_Wars), que permite 32 mil unidades, mesmo em computadores antigos rodava fácil (nunca consegui criar tantos "soldados"). Qual você acha que provavelmente usou o *Flyweight*?

Tem um [exemplo de árvores do cenário de jogos em um artigo](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/flyweight.html).

#### Editor de texto

Outro exemplo clássico é o uso de dados de formatação em um editor de textos. É comum que vários trechos possuam a mesma formatação. Pra que criar um objeto dizendo todas características daquele trecho se outro trecho tem exatamente a mesma característica?

Em casos extremos precisaria de um objeto para cada caractere do texto. Seria uma loucura. Tudo o que for repetido pode usar um objeto só e tudo que precisa daquela formatação a referencia.

[Veja uma implementação simplificada](http://www.dofactory.com/net/flyweight-design-pattern).

#### Outros exemplos

No [artigo da Wikipedia *linkado* na pergunta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) tem alguns exemplos que demonstram como o mecanismo funciona. Lá tem um exemplo de um serviço de café. Cada pedido atendido tem que referenciar um sabor de café, cada sabor tem seu objeto. Mas não tem porque criar um sabor de café igual para cada pedido. Se tiver 10 pedidos que pedem `Espresso`, basta existir apenas um `Espresso`.

Pense no estoque: quando falamos em um produto, falamos dele num sentido abstrato, em algo que é especificado. Não falamos de cada item físico que existe na empresa. Nesse ponto não tem porque criar um objeto de um produto para cada item físico existente. Ainda que precise do controle do produto físico único, ele não precisa ter todos os dados do produto no objeto, isso pode ser compartilhado. Algo assim:

```
class Produto { // existirão alguns, talvez milhares
    int Id;
    string Nome;
    decimal Preco;
    Cor Cor;
    .
    .
    .
}

class Item { // potencialmente existirão milhões
    int Id;
    int ProdutoId; //compõe aqui
    string Serial;
    DateTime Validade;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Other/Flyweight.cs).

Tem um site que fala de todos os padrões de forma bem descrita, com UML e exemplos. [Veja o Flyweight](http://www.oodesign.com/flyweight-pattern.html).

Tem outro com uma [abordagem um pouco diferente](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight).

É curioso que muitos padrões de projeto as pessoas usam e nem percebem. Esses são os melhores.

Comment: É possível afirmar que o Python adotou o Flyweight no seu gerenciador de memória?

Comment: Não saberia dizer, você tem alguma teoria sobre isso? Me parece que não, mas posso não estar vendo o mesmo que você.

Comment: Posso estar falando asneira, mas me pareceu bem casar com a ideia que você descreveu aí na resposta. É porque em Python, se você "cria" dois objetos imutáveis iguais (inteiros, strings, tuplas etc.) você, na verdade, está criando várias referências para o mesmo objeto, porque cada objeto imutável só existe uma vez na memória. Então ao executar `x = 50` e `y = 50`, `x` e `y` apontam para o mesmo endereço de memória. Isso não conta como alguma forma de Flyweight?

Comment: Parece que sim, mas só por observação, não sei te dizer detalhes e imagino que seja implementado assim, mas nada impede de não ser assim também. Não sei se gosto desta escolha.