# Por que a comparação de objetos diferentes retorna true?

Tags: java, objetos, int

Primeiro código:

```
Integer i1 = 1234;
Integer i2 = 1234;
System.out.println(i1 == i2); //false
System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); //true
```

Mesmo que pareça que estão sendo utilizados tipos primitivos, na verdade são objetos, logo, quando estes objetos são comparados usando `==` o resultado é `false`, já que são instâncias diferentes de `Integer`. Até aqui tudo bem.

Segundo código:

```
Integer i1 = 123;
Integer i2 = 123;
System.out.println(i1 == i2); //true
System.out.println(i1.equals(i2)); //true
```

Por que o resultado da primeira comparação é `true` e não `false` como no primeiro código?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Por causa do [*interning* (*Flyweight pattern*)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101). Esta técnica costuma ser percebida como um *cache*, e até é de certa forma, mas a principal vantagem é compartilhar o estado. Cache tradicional tem um conceito um pouco diferente, ele pode ser invalidado, tem tempo de vida restrito.

O Java decidiu que números pequenos deveriam ter esse compartilhamento porque o objeto tem um custo muito alto. Um `Integer` tem mais de 20 bytes de consumo. Provavelmente se não precisasse de um objeto nesses casos (Java 1x passa ter um mecanismo que permite evitar objetos caros para dados pequenos, mas veio um pouco tarde, tem uma base de código muito grande usando os objetos).

Os objetos que contenham um valor que caiba em 1 byte já está representado no código pelo *interning*, então todos os números `123` em objetos (não confundir com primitivos, como é o `int`) estarão na mesma posição de memória.

Pode se perguntar porque não fazer com os objetos que precisam de 2 ou 4 bytes. Só o de 2 bytes precisaria no mínimo de 128KB (na prática deve passar de 1MB), não costuma compensar já que a maioria não será usado.

Entrando no campo da opinião é que isso não deveria ser feito, mas até entendo que conserta um pouco o problema que nem deveria existir, não deveria usar objetos de mais de 20 bytes para guardar uma informação tão trivial, ou até objetos não deveriam ocupar tanto espaço, o que não resolveria, mas já ajudaria o problema.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 6):

O Java, para economizar memória, mantém um **cache** de alguns objetos, e toda vez que é feito um boxing (transformação de primitivos em wrappers) ele os reutiliza.

Os seguintes objetos são mantidos no cache:

- Todos `Boolean` e `Byte`;
- `Short` e `Integer` de -128 até 127;
- `Caracter` ASCII, como letras, números, etc;

Então, no segundo código, o objeto realmente é o mesmo, pois é um Integer, dentro da faixa do cache.

Mais detalhes na [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7).