# Qual a diferenca entre String nome = "teste" e String s4 = new String("Pedro");

Tags: java, string, orientação-a-objetos, construtor

Qual a diferença de se atribuir um valor a variável criando um objeto e atribuindo *unboxing* a um valor direto?

```
String s4 = new String("nome");


String nome = "nome";
System.out.println("nome == s4 " + (nome == s4)); //retorna false
```

Se eu comparar essas duas variáveis com `==` vai dar `false`, porém com `equals()` é igual a `true`. Esses conceitos eu entendi bem.

Por que não dá igual se eu atribuir outra variável?

```
String nome2 = "nome";
System.out.println("nome == nome2 " + (nome == nome2)); //resultado true
```

Comment: Se atribuir o  valor a uma variavel sem criar um objeto, ele cria o valor na mesma variavel da memoria?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

O operador `==` compara se dois objetos apontam para o mesmo local de memória e o `equals()` compara o conteúdo dos objetos.

Dá essa igualdade por causa do chamado [*interning*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101), onde dois valores iguais são armazenados no mesmo local, desde que eles sejam imutáveis e determinados em tempo de compilação. É o caso do literal *string*. Então o `"nome"` em toda aplicação só existe um, inclusive o que está sendo usado como argumento do construtor da classe `String` usado no primeiro exemplo.

Há diferença quando no caso do literal o compilador já pode determinar o local do objeto e no caso do uso do construtor não pode, afinal o argumento poderia ser uma variável.

Pode perguntar se o compilador não poderia otimizar esse caso já que o construtor usa um literal. Poderia, mas provavelmente não vale o esforço porque geralmente não costuma-se usar o construtor com um literal, e se usar provavelmente usou porque não quer o *interning*.

As variáveis são diferentes, mas elas apontam pro mesmo objeto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obg foi ótimo sua explicação, bigown♦ porque sempre pensei os valores de uma string são como objeto, so que nesse caso como unbox, mas ai ele está sendo "referenciado" como um literal, ai nesse caso permanece no mesmo local os valores.

Comment: Como *string* é um tipo por referência não cabe *boxing*.

Answer (score 3):

Apesar da excelente resposta escolhida, gostaria de complementar com alguns links.

O conceito de boxing e unboxing só existe para os tipos primitivos. Veja:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.8

Uma `String`, literal ou não, é um tipo referência.

[Segundo a documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html), o código baixo:

```java
String str = "abc";
```

É equivalente a isso:

```java
String str = new String(new char[] {'a', 'b', 'c'});
```

Ou seja, sempre que vc usa uma `String` literal, está implicitamente, criando uma instância com aquele valor entre aspas duplas.

Não importa se vc usa a mesma `String` literal em mais de um lugar, pois, graças ao processo que o @Maniero explicou, uma `String` literal sempre vai apontar para a mesma instância.

É por isso que o código abaixo retorna `true`:

```java
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = "abc";
String s3 = "abc";
System.out.println(s1 == s2 == s3);
```

Já quando vc faz isso:

```java
String str = new String("abc");
```

Na verdade estará criando 2 instâncias de `String`, uma que é criada implicitamente pelo uso do literal e outra explicitamente pelo uso do constructor.

É por isso que o código abaixo retorna `false`, já que o operador de igualdade verifica se as instâncias — não o valor contido no objeto — são as mesmas.

```java
String s1 = "abc";
String s2 = new String("abc");
System.out.println(s1 == s2);
```

Veja o que diz a [documentação deste constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.lang.String)):

> Initializes a newly created String object so that it represents the same sequence of characters as the argument; in other words, the newly created string is a copy of the argument string. Unless an explicit copy of original is needed, use of this constructor is unnecessary since Strings are immutable.

Vale olhar a [especificação também](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5).

> Moreover, a string literal always refers to the same instance of class String. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.29) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, as if by execution of the method String.intern (§12.5).