# Comportamento do malloc(1) em C

Tags: c, string, memória, alocação, malloc

Se eu usar `char *char_commandout = (char *) malloc(1);`, o byte alocado irá armazenar o "\0" na posição 0 do vetor ou irá alocar um espaço para o valor que eu quero armazenar (na posição 0) e um para o "\0" (na posição 1)?

Comment: Uma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nenhum dos dois. O `malloc` aloca a área de memória, mas não a limpa. Assim sendo, qualquer conteúdo que estivesse abandonado lá vai continuar lá (esse conteúdo é carinhosamente denomidado de **lixo**). Por isso, o conteúdo do ponteiro após o `malloc` pode ser qualquer coisa, pois contém lixo.

É recomendado escrever algo na memória alocada para evitar que você acesse conteúdo que seja lixo, o que provavelmente faria o programa se comportar de forma incorreta.

Se você chamar `malloc(1)`, será devolvido um ponteiro que aponta para 1 byte de memória alocada. Pode até ser que o `malloc` internamente reserve uma área maior por questão de desempenho, mas a única garantia que existe é que 1 byte de memória reservada lhe será devolvido (reservada, mas não limpa), e que se você acessar além do limite (o segundo byte, na posição 1), estará acessando uma área de memória não reservada (o que pode causar uma falha de segmentação, acessar o conteúdo de alguma outra variável ou então ler ou escrever lixo em algum lugar).

Comment: _Carinhosamente chamado de lixo_ ROFL

Comment: @MarceloUchimura ele falou isso porque os floquinhos de neve sempre acabam pensando "aí, ele falou lixo, isso é feio, ele é mal, ele não é educado, não tem empatia", aí tem que dar volta para dar o nome do que é aquilo sem ofender alguém e rolar mimimi, o que é o orifício excretor ofídico. Bom, pode não sera intenção oficial dele, mas é isso... :)

Comment: A polícia do politicamente correto até na área de TI, velho... e eu pensando, quando criança, que ia viver de pegar no joystick do Atari kkk

Comment: Pra quem não sabe, Atari é um negão parrudo, maior que um PS4.

Comment: Agora tem um pequeno, e caro pro burro. Dá pra fazer do tamanho de um pendrive (não aqueles q é só uma tampinha) que custa uns 100 reais e q tem todos os jogos dele

Comment: No meu código, eu pretendo criar uma string com 2 bytes (um para um char e outro para o "\0") para depois poder usar o realloc para aumentar o tamanho da string de acordo com o que o usuário inserir (alocação dinâmica). A minha dúvida é se ao usar malloc(1), eu posso já usar esse espaço para armazenar o primeiro char da minha string. Desculpe se você já respondeu isso, mas não peguei essa parte.

Answer (score 8):

O Victor já deu a resposta base da dúvida, vou acrescentar que é comum as pessoas usarem um [`memset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) para zerar a memória quando necessário. Quando é necessário o [`calloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) pode ser usado para alocar e já zerar. Em tese é possível ter otimizações, talvez até em conjunto com o sistema operacional para ganhar performance, mas não conte com isto, inclusive porque sequer o [`c/re/malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc) precisar ser o original. A diferença pro [`malloc()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) é a limpeza dos dados.

No caso de interpretar o dado como uma *string*, e em C você pode interpretar como quiser, um 1 byte zerado será uma *string* com 0 caracteres, o [`\0` será o terminador da *string*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177619/101).

Em C não é adequado fazer *cast* do resultado do `malloc()`, isto pode esconder erros, então o que deseja é só:

```
char *char_commandout = calloc(1);
```

Porém de forma geral isto não faz sentido porque você já sabe o conteúdo e ele não pode mudar de forma útil e correta, mesmo que precise de uma *string* de tamanho 0 o ideal é fazer isso estaticamente, até mesmo usado o [Flyweight](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/101).

Outra curiosidade que não faz o menor sentido é usar

```
malloc(sizeof(char))
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Allocation/MallocSize1.c).

É garantido por especificação que `char` tem sempre o tamanho 1, no fundo ele é 1 byte. Há quem argumente que um dia pode mudar, o que é risível, principalmente porque sempre é dito por um programador "experiente".

Geralmente alocações no *heap* acima de 8 bytes, até mesmo 16 fazem bem pouco sentido e nos casos que faz seria o caso de repensar se pode fazer de outra forma. Em coisas pequenas acima o consumo de memória pra controlar a alocação é maior que o dado em si. Claro que não é a única forma de decidir, tem coisas que precisam de uma alocação por tempo indeterminado, mas também quase sempre dá para evitar isto. Na prática a alocação será muito maior que 1 byte, mas você só poderá acessar 1 byte, e ai de você se tentar acessar mais que um antes ou depois dele, até funcionará, mas para seu bem tomara que o código quebre em seguida.

Comment: No meu código, eu pretendo criar uma string com 2 bytes (um para um char e outro para o "\0") para depois poder usar o realloc para aumentar o tamanho da string de acordo com o que o usuário inserir (alocação dinâmica). A minha dúvida é se ao usar malloc(1), eu posso já usar esse espaço para armazenar o primeiro char da minha string. Desculpe se você já respondeu isso, mas não peguei essa parte.

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas reservar 1 byte e querer colocar 2 acho que não vai dar certo. Mas como eu disse essa estratégia (mesmo 2 bytes) sequer deve ser adequada. Na verdade tem cara que sequer precisa fazer essa alocação que está querendo.

Comment: Vou colocar a função que criei na minha pergunta

Comment: @Cooper só tem um pequeno detalhe, a gente já respondeu o que você perguntou, agora precisa fazer outra pergunta. E aparentemente você não leu minha resposta, e por isso, e não só por isso, já adianto que seu código não faz o menor sentido.