# Comparação de objeto no "Flyweight pattern"

Tags: flyweight

Estava lendo [essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/165105/92908), e fiquei na dúvida sobre como é feita a comparação entre os objetos, assim, determinar qual objeto seria igual ao outro, e qual seria um novo objeto.

Usando o exemplo da mesma questão citada, sobre o jogo "Age of Empires", onde tinha milhares de **guerreiros do tipo X**, e outros **Y** com um mesmo padrão de "propriedades", mas apenas mudavam **cores**, ou até os mesmos **guerreiros X**, que eram **do inimigo**, surgem algumas questões, entre elas:

- É criado um novo objeto antes da comparação ou se é comparado apenas propriedades ao criar, com algum outro já criado?
- Esse comparativo é feito do objeto por inteiro, com cada propriedade do mesmo?
- Contando que teríamos N objetos iguais dos guerreiros, mas a propriedade vida, vivo/morto, será alterada, e aí? Como trataria num mesmo objeto, com propriedades diferentes?
- Como é feita a ordenação para comparação? Existem critérios (tipo um índice)?