# Por que ainda usar a String em vez de StringBuilder no Java?

Tags: java, string, desempenho, stringbuilder

Como muitos já devem saber, criar objetos de `StringBuilder` podem salvar e muito o desempenho de nossas aplicações em Java, já que são muito mais rápidas do que uma `String`.

Isso se deve pelo fato de que a `StringBuilder` é mutável diferentemente da `String`, que cria novos objetos a cada concatenação que façamos.

A minha pergunta é: por que ainda se usa `String` em Java? Por que não deveríamos usar apenas a `StringBuilder` nas nossas aplicações?

Comment: De certa forma, lendo por cima me parece que está bem respondido aqui já: [String e sua eficiência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16050/70) inclusive com links para aprofundar mais sobre StringBuilder e StringBuffer.

Comment: Eu li essa pergunta antes de fazer a minha. Só que nessa questão ele só fala sobre o que é StringBuilder e o que é String. Eu estou a procura de algo mais aprofundado sobre se é realmente ainda útil uma String (uma comparação entre String e StringBuffer e não a definição delas).

Comment: Tem uma opção, quando você oferece bônus em uma pergunta, que é de pedir resposta com mais detalhes: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfMMx.png

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Como muitos já devem saber, criar objetos de `StringBuilder` podem salvar e muito o desempenho de nossas aplicações em Java, já que são muito mais rápidas do que uma `String`.

Não são, teve época inclusive que SB era pior em alguns cenários, não sei quais ainda acontece isso porque esse tipo de coisa é detalhe de implementação.

> Isso se deve pelo fato de que a `StringBuilder` é mutável diferentemente da `String`, que cria novos objetos a cada concatenação que façamos.

Só neste caso fica mais rápido. O nome já diz tudo, esse tipo serve só para construir uma *string*.

> Por que ainda se usa `String` em Java? Por que não deveríamos usar apenas a `StringBuilder` nas nossas aplicações?

Porque na imensa maioria dos casos não fazemos mutações na *string*. E as pessoas vão começar abusar da mutabilidade de textos onde não precisa.

E porque objetos mutáveis não funcionam bem em ambiente concorrente, que é cada vez mais comum, complicaria muito toda a aplicação ter que lidar com isso.

Ainda é comum mapas (dicionários, tabelas *hash*) usarem *strings* como chave, e chaves precisam de dados imutáveis para funcionar bem (um mudança precisa reorganizar todo mapa).

Reflexão também tem problemas parecidos em alguns cenários.

E dados mutáveis não se dão bem com cache, e ainda dificultam reaproveitamento por [*interning*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164960/o-que-%C3%A9-flyweight-pattern).

Do ponto de vista de segurança é mais fácil fazer acesso indevido em uma *string* mutável.

Sem falar que o objeto `stringBuilder` é mais complexo internamente.

Nem entrei no mérito que não dá mais para mudar com o carro andando. A classe atual é extremamente limitada. Precisa mudar muito o que já existe para ter o mesmo poder e flexibilidade da `String`. E todas as APIs atuais aceitam `String`, não `StringBuilder`.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).