# Em Ruby, o que são símbolos (dois-pontos seguido de identificador) e onde podem ser usados?

Tags: ruby, característica-linguagem, identificador

Código Ruby possui o que a linguagem chama de símbolos (*symbols*), que são identificadores precedidos por dois-pontos, por exemplo `:nome`, `:idade`, `:peso`.

Sabemos que cada nome utilizado dessa forma no código é único e imutável, sendo portanto uma instância única e imutável de alguma coisa (pertencente à classe `Symbol` aparentemente). Dois símbolos com mesmo identificador são o mesmo símbolo.

Com isso eles podem ser usados para identificar parâmetros em métodos e chaves em *hashes* (mapeamentos chave-valor), entre outros possíveis usos que não sei bem quais são.

Mas conceitualmente falando, o que é um símbolo em Ruby? Existe precisão em dizer que eu posso interpretá-lo como uma string constante internalizada *a la* Java no código? Acho que a pergunta-chave que quero fazer é, como devo "traduzir" (interpretar sintatica/semanticamente) um símbolo no código para entender como ele está se comportando?

Por exemplo, não me recordo bem, mas acho que símbolos podem ser usados no lugar de nomes de métodos, seja na declaração ou na chamada. Seria um identificador do método, uma referência a esse método...?

Talvez a dúvida colocada de forma mais precisa seja, que tipo de informação um símbolo substitui no código?

Enfim: o que são, onde podem ser utilizados e como devem ser compreendidos?

**EDIT:** Lembro do projetinho de compiladores na faculdade que tinha um tipo de token lido pelo analisador léxico (*scanner*) que era chamado de identificador (o que ele identificava dependia do contexto a ser analisado posteriormente, se era variável, nome de função, etc).

Nesse contexto, um símbolo seria um identificador de escopo global no código? Por outro lado, isso me causa confusão porque `:minha_funcao` e `minha_funcao` são teoricamente diferentes em Ruby (ou não são?).

Comment: ótimo questionamento! poderia esclarecer um pouco mais a parte que fala da "pergunta-chave", por favor?

Comment: @vinibrsl Tentei esclarecer com a edição, obrigado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## O que são símbolos?

Símbolos no Ruby são objetos usados para representar nomes de forma [imutável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15510/o-que-imut%C3%A1vel-realmente-significa) e que não passam pelo [coletor de lixo](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/GC.html). É uma funcionalidade da linguagem mais semântica do que performática ou qualquer outro motivo.

Como em muitos casos uma string e um símbolo são intercambiáveis, houveram equívocos na sua utilização dentro da própria linguagem, como por exemplo:

```
Ruby 1.8> URI.methods
["decode_www_form_component", "parse", "split", ...]

Ruby 1.9+> URI.methods
[:decode_www_form_component, :parse, :split, ...]
```

Para mostrar a imutabilidade, vamos usar o método `Object#object_id`, da [própria documentação do Ruby](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html). Perceba que para todas as variáveis, independente do escopo, o identificador único do objeto é o mesmo.

```
module One
  class Fred
  end
  $f1 = :Fred
end

module Two
  Fred = 1
  $f2 = :Fred
end

def Fred()
end

$f3 = :Fred
$f1.object_id   #=> 2514190
$f2.object_id   #=> 2514190
$f3.object_id   #=> 2514190
```

Dessa forma, pode aproximar o conceito de símbolo à string constante internalizada no Java, ou também [no Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.intern). Existem linguagens como Elixir que possuem estruturas como símbolos, que é o caso do [Atom](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/Atom.html).

## Métodos são símbolos?

Não, métodos não são símbolos. Porém, como usamos símbolos para nomes definidos, que podem ser usados mais de uma vez, e menos "voláteis" na perspectiva da mutabilidade, um método pode ser chamado com metaprogramação usando um símbolo.

```
Ruby> "Hello".upcase # forma normal de fazer
"HELLO"

Ruby> "Hello".send :upcase # metaprogramação
"HELLO"
```

E tal forma de se fazer não tem nada a ver com o símbolo. É só que quem criou esse método `Object#send` resolveu que aceitaria um símbolo, ao invés de qualquer outra **forma de se representar o nome do método a ser chamado**. O símbolo está ali para representar e identificar o método a ser chamado, mas não contém nada além do que o nome.

## Quando usar um símbolo? E quando não usar?

Use símbolos para quando você precisa de identificadores internos, como enumeradores, representar nomes de funções, chaves em hashes. E só converta strings para símbolos que você conhece, isto é, se seu sistema aceita inputs externos e converte estes para símbolos, você pode ter um vazamento de memória.

Comment: Valeu Vini, votei na sua que foi respondida primeiro e de forma bem abrangente sobre tudo o que perguntei, mas as três respostas dadas até agora estão no mesmo altíssimo nível (se o meu Dunning-K. permite identificar kkkk). Basicamente um identificador no código-fonte é um símbolo (numa acepção computacional) que desaparece na compilação/execução, mas não é o mesmo que um símbolo do Ruby, que é um identificador "internalizado" no runtime (talvez não seja "internalizado" o termo que estou buscando) e "exposto" ao programa para ser acessado e identificar coisas em tempo de execução. Seria isso?

Comment: É isso mesmo! Pois é, essa pergunta rendeu respostas da nata do SOpt. Fico feliz que tenha escolhido minha resposta :)

Answer (score 4):

Isto é um [Symbol](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html).

Símbolo em computação significa que é um nome a ser usado pelo código. Um nome de variável, função, *label* ou tipo é um símbolo.

Como já deve saber (e se não sabe tem muita informação no site sobre o assunto), um nome, ou seja, um símbolo, de um código desaparece em muitas situações. Mesmo onde não desaparece ele acaba sendo usado de uma forma um pouco menos direta do que parece.

Então ele é um objeto que te interessa o nome dele, mas não o valor, o que é um pouco incomum em muitas situações. Mas ele é um objeto como outro qualquer e pode ser usado onde outros objetos também podem.

Um dos usos mais interessantes é em um dicionário ([ou mapa ou como queira chamar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/429851/101)). Em vez de ter chaves que são *strings*, pode usar símbolos, o que será mais eficiente porque ele pode ser acessado de forma única e fácil sem analisar o texto escrito que é um processamento que pode ser pesado, e tem complexidade de algoritmo linear ao tamanho do texto.

O Símbolo tem complexidade constante porque ele só tem que pegar algum número (um endereço de memória) associado ao símbolo, que é único. É muito melhor.

Eles podem ter valor, e podem ser usados como um `enum`, geralmente dentro de um outro objeto.

Portanto ele não é uma *string*, pelo contrário. Existe alguma intercambialidade com *string*, mas não é a mesma coisa. Você sempre usou o conceito, mas sempre associado com aspectos do código e não como um objeto livre assim. Pense nele como uma variável que o valor não costuma ser importante.

Ele não é diretamente uma referência para um método, mas um símbolo chamado de `x` não pode existir de forma separada de um método chamado `x`. Ou seja, um método `x` tem um símbolo chamado `x`, portanto aí é uma referência para o método. Como o é em qualquer linguagem que tenha funções como [cidadão de primeira classe](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/227485/101).

O símbolo é um identificador de escopo global.

O nome sem o `:` não pode ser usado:

```
module Teste
    def minha_funcao
        puts 'função'
    end
end
puts Teste.method_defined?(:minha_funcao)
#puts Teste.method_defined?(minha_funcao)
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/S0c0Vv). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/ebiwjgbnqs-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Ruby/Symbol.rb).

Comment: Não pode ser usado mas acabou de usar na hora de declarar a função. :) Nesse momento o identificador `minha_funcao` equivaleu a `:minha_funcao`? Acho que a confusão na minha cabeça é ver os dois no código e não saber se são a mesma coisa "conceitualmente".

Comment: A coisa feia do Ruby é que `Class.method_defined?("send")` também funciona.

Comment: Sim, eles apontam para o mesmo endereço. Você pode usar sem o `:` quando está declarando no código ou chamando usando `()`, mas não pode usar de forma direta, só ele. Precisa de um operador. @vinibrsl não sei se é feia se considerar a característica da linguagem. Ela é toda assim. JS é uma bomba, mas nunca reclamei que x.y na verdade é x["y"], isso em si não é um problema. E isso aí até C# tem, pra mim o feito é todo objeto ter isso dentro dele, C# é algo à parte, opcional, é só uma flexibilidade. Mas é característica, cada um com sua vantagem.

Answer (score 4):

#### Introdução

Em Ruby, `string`s são mutáveis. A partir daí já dá para começar a entender a motivação por trás do `symbol`.

Além disso, quando se cria dois símbolos iguais em locais diferentes do código, terá um *mesmo* objeto na memória. Todavia, quando se cria duas strings (mesmo que totalmente iguais caractere a caractere), terá *dois* objetos diferentes.

Com isso, cria-se, em Ruby, uma distinção entre strings e símbolos. Strings são úteis para representar um *dado* (como o nome de uma pessoa, por exemplo). Símbolos são úteis para representar um *identificador*. E por isso estes têm que ser mais rápidos.

Claro que, em linguagens onde toda string é imutável por definição (como JavaScript), essa distinção não faz muito sentido. Tanto é que o código em JavaScript `Object.create`, por exemplo, acessa a função qualificada como `create` (uma autêntica string) no objeto `Object`. Em Ruby seria algo como `Object[:create]`.

#### Internalização de strings

O mecanismo utilizado para implementar isso chama-se [*string interning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). E sim, tal como colocado na própria pergunta, é também utilizado pelo *interning* em Java.

Ao custo de criar um novo registro no *interner pool* durante a criação do símbolo, esse mecanismo provê grandes ganhos na comparação de strings internalizadas. Ao invés de comparar caractere a caractere, basta comparar o número associado no *interner pool*. Veja mais no artigo da Wikipedia, já linkado, e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164960/69296).

E esse ganho faz muito sentido no caso de uso adotado para símbolos em Ruby. Símbolos são frequentemente utilizados como **identificadores** – como pode haver vários identificadores com um nome comum, há bastante ganho (por exemplo em custo de comparação e em memória).

#### O que são?

O `symbol` é um primitivo imutável em Ruby. É análogo, *de certo modo*, a uma string, só que com profundas diferenças nos mecanismos internos.

Essa discrepância em mecanismo estabelece diferenças, tanto de performance quanto na semântica do código. Por conta disso, em Ruby, você vai usar símbolos em um lugar, e strings em outro...

#### Onde podem ser utilizados?

Strings devem ser utilizadas para representar um dado. Por exemplo, o nome de um usuário, um endereço ou qualquer outra coisa do tipo. Repare que isso não é um nome, um identificador.

Símbolos, por sua natureza, devem ser entendidos como *identificadores*. A diferença na performance torna-os perfeitos para isso. Tanto é que você utiliza símbolos e não strings em um *hash*.

Seria muito custoso usar strings em identificadores ou em chaves de mapas. Imagine criar uma nova string para cada chave de um array de objetos. Além do custo adicional de performance para cada nova alocação, teria que envolver mais memória também.

Embora [não seja possível dizer que métodos ou variáveis sejam símbolos em Ruby](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/24461), símbolos podem ser utilizados para despachar uma ação a um método. É a famosa orientação a objetos à lá mensageria. Referir à `send` – veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3337285/7445826) e [aqui](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#method-i-send).

Símbolos são globais ao programa. Você pode utilizar a função [`Symbol.all_symbols`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Symbol.html#method-c-all_symbols) para obter todos os símbolos já registrados.

Comment: _"Embora não seja possível dizer que métodos ou variáveis sejam símbolos em Ruby"_ não eles, mas seus identificadores sim, pelo menos foi essa a interpretação que eu dei à resposta do Maniero. Essa interpretação foi correta? PS: Agora li a do vinibrsl em que classes, funções, etc. diferentes são identificadas com o mesmo símbolo, complicou um pouco mais :P rs mas foi bom que desvinculou uma coisa da outra.

Comment: @Piovezan, pois é, embora eu não seja ávido conhecedor de Ruby, diria que sim – no sentido de que os identificadores são expostos ou referidos como símbolos. Pelo menos, no nível da linguagem, ao invés de usar strings para se referir a um método, por exemplo, você utiliza um `symbol`. Agora, internamente, símbolos e identificadores podem ser outra coisa, mas aí eu já não sei dizer.