# Qual é a diferença entre IsNullOrEmpty() e IsNullOrWhiteSpace()?

Tags: c#, .net, string, vb.net

Li [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151123/41056) que não existe diferença prática entre `String.Empty` e `""`, e então me veio a dúvida.

Qual é a diferença entre usar `String.IsNullOrEmpty(String)` e `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String)`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Ambos verificam se é nulo, isto parece óbvio. Vamos às diferenças.

Ao primeiro só interessa se o tamanho do texto é zero, ou seja, se tem zero caracteres. Então se tiver um simples espaço já não é mais vazio.

O tempo de execução é constante - O(1).

O segundo analisa caractere por caractere se cada um deles é um dos caracteres considerados um branco (não precisa ser necessariamente um espaço, pode ser tabulação, quebra de linha ou outro de acordo com as regras do Unicode ou Latin1, as duas codificações que ele entende). Se tiver um caractere que não seja branco ele retorna falso e encerra. Se todos os caracteres forem considerados espaços, mesmo que tenha vários, retorna verdadeiro.

O tempo de execução é linear O(n) no pior caso. Se nenhum caractere for não branco, irá até o tamanho do texto. Se o primeiro caractere já for não branco, ele encerra a busca ali mesmo e equivalerá ao O(1) que é o melhor caso.

Pode ser visto no próprio fonte do .NET.

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) => (value == null || value.Length == 0);
```

[Fonte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,23a8597f842071f4). No [.NET 5 em diante](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,23a8597f842071f4).

```
public static bool IsNullOrWhiteSpace(String value) {
    if (value == null) return true;
    for (int i = 0; i < value.Length; i++) if (!Char.IsWhiteSpace(value[i])) return false;
    return true;
}
```

[Fonte](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55e241b6143365ef). No [.NET 5 em diante](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/String.cs,55e241b6143365ef).

Pode ser testado com esse código:

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string nullString = null;
        string emptyString = "";
        string spaceString = "    ";
        string tabString = "\t";
        string newlineString = "\n";
        string nonEmptyString = "texto";
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(nullString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(emptyString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(spaceString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(tabString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(newlineString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrEmpty(nonEmptyString));
        WriteLine();
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nullString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(emptyString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(spaceString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tabString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(newlineString));
        WriteLine(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nonEmptyString));
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Kz3HR0). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TrclCR). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/NullWhiteSpace.cs).

Comment: Dúvida. Olhando o fonte do c#, é um método estático comum. Como ele identifica que é possível utilizar isso em strings? Digo isso pq se fosse uma extensão seria mais fácil de entender...

Comment: Na verdade eu acho mais fácil (ainda que seja quase igual) identificar assim , seja para o compilador, seja para um humano. Eu até fico na dúvida que dúvida teria, porque explicitamente está chamando através da classe `string`. fora isso o parâmetro é do tipo `string`.

Comment: Certo, mas quando temos um literal "" é feito parse para classe string?

Comment: Isso é um dado do tipo `string`. Dá para ver no código da resposta.

Comment: Estou confundindo as coisas. Na verdade a dúvida é: Pq temos que usar `string.IsNullOrEmpty("")` ou invés de `"".IsNullOrEmpty()`? Estilo função `ToUpper`.

Comment: Isso é interessante. Não para o literal, esse sempre funcionará, mas o mais com não é usar um literal, porque se usar você já sabe a resposta só olhando para o código, não precisa processar nada. Mas com uma variável o objeto pode ser nulo e quebraria a aplicação tentar acessar um objeto pelo seu valor nulo, então o método estático funciona sempre, você chama o método e passa um valor que seja `string` incluindo um nulo é possível. Método estático é uma função independente, método de instância depende da instância existir, e o valor nulo indica que ela não existe.

Answer (score 18):

O [`string.IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) é a mesma coisa que:

```
result = s == null || s == String.Empty;
```

e o [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) é a mesma coisa que:

```
result = string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || s.Trim().Length == 0;
```

ou seja, o [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) tem as verificações do [`IsNullOrEmpty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx) e `Length == 0`.

Segundo [site dotnetperls](https://www.dotnetperls.com/isnullorwhitespace), o desempenho do [`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx) não é muito bom.

***Referencias:***

- [Método String.IsNullOrEmpty (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorempty(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Método String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [IsNullOrWhiteSpace](https://www.dotnetperls.com/isnullorwhitespace)
- [C# compare string is null or empty](http://qiita.com/cashwu/items/f17785655a515b534896)