# C# - Como verificar se uma string tem só espaços?

Tags: c#, string

O propgrama lê todas linhas de um arquivo, e tenho que verificar se nessa linha que ele está lendo tem só espaços, pois se tiver só espaços nela, ela será considerada inválida pelo programa. Como faço para verificar se ela tem só espaços(" ")?

Comment: relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/172694/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-isnullorempty-e-isnullorwhitespace

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simples, use:`string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(suaString)`
Por exemplo:

```
string nome = "         ";
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nome))
{
    //Sua função
}
```

Comment: apenas um comentário: `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` só está disponível a partir do .NET 3.5. Mas acredito que isso não faz diferença =]

Answer (score 3):

você pode fazer assim:

```
string texto = "   ";
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(texto) || texto.Trim().Length == 0)
{
   //a string só tem espaços ou não tem nada
}
```