# Testar se há preenchimento de string

Tags: c#, .net, string

Ao ler um *post* sobre boas práticas de programação, mais relacionado à validar o preenchimento de strings, me deparei com o seguinte:

Verificação muito lenta:

```
string ret = String.Empty;

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ret))
```

Verificação lenta:

```
string ret = String.Empty;

if (ret == "")
```

Verificação Performática:

```
string ret = String.Empty;

if (ret.Length == 0)
```

Ao ver isso eu fiquei com muita dúvida, pois no local onde trabalho muita gente já havia me falado para utilizar o `string.IsNullOrEmpty()`, mas depois de ver isso estou me questionando.

Então se alguém puder esclarecer o porquê dessa diferença de performance, ou até mesmo se essa informação é real seria interessante.

E caso realmente haja uma forma ideal entre essas 3 formas de verificar o preenchimento de uma *string*, as outras 2 podem ser "descartadas", ou a utilização varia de caso para caso?

Comment: Eu declararia string ret = String.Empty; apenas

Comment: Obrigado pela observação, vou editar a pergunta. Coloquei daquele jeito apenas para exemplificar a existencia daquela string, mas pode gerar duvida pelo fato de, nesse caso, sempre dar NullPointer nos exemplos 2 e 3.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pare de ler boas práticas! Isso só cria vícios de programação e ilusão que está aprendendo programar melhor. Estude os fundamentos, entenda porque as coisas funcionam daquele jeito, pesquise e veja por conta próprio ou pergunte para especialistas que podem ser contestados e avaliados por outras pessoas, como está fazendo agora (no passado era mais confiável, hoje o site avalia respostas com problemas como se fossem boas, então também não é tão confiável).

Você fez os testes? Da forma correta? Tem certeza que viu qual é mais lenta? Na situação correta? Tome muito cuidado com testes que não tem controle do ambiente. Vejo muito erro quando a pessoa vai testar e aí dá resultados diferentes da realidade. E mesmo que dê certo, no uso normal pode ser que o resultado seja diferente do teste real e correto, porque o código não executa isoladamente. Eu fiz o teste da resposta do Rodolfo e na minha máquina, nas condições da minha solução, deu resultado diferente, inclusive em execuções diferentes o resultado não foi muito consistente.

Não acontece, mas poderia ter um compilador que analisa todo o contexto (e nem é tão difícil assim em certos casos) e poderia ver que a maior parte dele não é necessária e eliminar tudo.

Ok, intuitivamente até acredito estar certo, mas só um teste correto pode garantir.

O primeiro faz algo diferente dos demais, então já estamos comparando laranjas com bananas. Ele verifica se a *string* é nula antes de verificar o conteúdo. Se a semântica é diferente já complica a comparação. Aí eu tenho que perguntar: você pode garantir que a *string* não é nula?

Eu já dei uma [resposta sobre o assunto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/172694/101) e este método na verdade faz apenas duas coisas: verifica se é nulo e se o seu tamanho é 0. Então já podemos concluir que o próprio .NET prefere verificar o tamanho, e faz sentido, porque evita uma comparação com [indireção](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181032/101) de memória e compara numericamente uma constante. Lá podemos verificar que o `IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` é potencialmente muito menos performático e desperdício de recursos se não o que precisa, e a semântica é diferente em certas situações.

Se puder garantir que não é nula então a terceira opção é melhor. Posso afirmar isso sem testar pelo conhecimento que tenho, mas poderia ter alguma otimização e não ser diferente. Nada impede o compilador ou [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) identificar o que quer e trocar por um código mais performático. E isso pode mudar de versão para versão, então se quer uma informação certeira, precisa testar a versão que vai usar, na plataforma que vai usar. Enfim, tudo pode influenciar.

Se quer garantir a melhor performance não conte que haverá otimização. Mas raramente isto é realmente necessário.

E claro, eu evitaria o segundo sempre que possível porque ele tende a não ser otimizado. Eu descartaria o primeiro se garantir que não é nulo, o que eu costumo garantir já e mais ainda no C# 8.

Se alguém achar um motivo para usar outra forma precisa justificar.

Como nota útil, em C# 8 é possível garantir que a `string` e outros tipos por referência nunca sejam nulos em tempo de compilação, então qualquer comparação com nulo será desnecessária, a não ser que o tipo seja declarado como anulável (`string?`).

---

#### Nota

Esta parte não faz mais sentido porque a pergunta foi editada, mas pode ser útil para outras pessoas.

Por fim nesse caso específico postado na pergunta eu faria assim (é isso mesmo, não é erro de visualização):

Se eu declarar uma variável do tipo `string` e não colocar valor algum ela será nula com certeza, não tem que mais nada para fazer, nem precisa verificar se é nula, ainda mais se tem alguma coisa. E claro, os exemplos 2 e 3 darão erro. Então não é que seja boa prática, apenas só faz sentido fazer nada. Respondi considerando que o exemplo foi um erro e a intenção é em outro contexto.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Isso, os exemplo 2 e 3 não tem a string iniciada mas não era a intenção provocar o NullPointerException, era apenas para exemplificar a existência daquela string mesmo. Obrigado pela atenção e resposta, sanou a minha dúvida.

Comment: Quando é assim, coloque qualquer texto, até vazio se for o caso.

Answer (score 6):

A versão de código "performática" vai dar erro `System.NullReferenceException` se a variável for null, acredito que terás que alterar para `if (ret == null || ret.Length == 0)`.

Fiz o seguinte teste:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string ret = null;

        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i <= 100000; i++)
        {
            // if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ret)) Console.WriteLine($"{i} empty string");
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ret)) Console.WriteLine($"{i} empty string");
        }

        stopWatch.Stop();
        // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
        TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;

        // Format and display the TimeSpan value.
        string elapsedTime = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}.{3:00}",
            ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds,
            ts.Milliseconds / 10);
        Console.WriteLine("RunTime " + elapsedTime);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Aqui estão os resultados:

**if (ret == null || ret.Length == 0)**

> RunTime 00:00:07.95

**if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ret))**

> RunTime 00:00:08.43

Eu confesso que nunca me preocupei com esse tipo de otimização, costumo usar `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace()` que já verifica também espaços em branco, mas é claro que tem que ver caso a caso o que é melhor usar.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!

Answer (score 5):

Penso que a questão da performance dos dois primeiros exemplos está relacionada com o facto de estarem a validar o conteúdo da `string`, onde no 3º exemplo, mais *performante*, apenas estamos a validar o tamanho.

### `string.IsNullOrEmpty(ret)`

Neste exemplo, o método `IsNullOrEmpty` representa, internamente, `ret == null || ret == string.Empty`, onde basicamente estamos a fazer duas comparações para validar o resultado.

Tendo em conta que `ret == string.Empty` representa `string.Equals(ret, String.Empty)` onde basicamente compara se o 1º objeto é igual ao 2º, atendendo se um deles é `null` e mesmo comparando caracter a caracter num *loop*, compreende-se o porquê de ser a opção **mais lenta** (até porque temos ainda a comparação com o `null`).

### `ret == ""`

Neste caso, como já explicado acima, `ret == ""` representa `string.Equals(ret, "")` que "arrasta" alguma complexidade na comparação e, por isso, é lenta mas menos que a anterior porque não tem a validação "extra" do `ret == null`.

### `ret.Length == 0`

Esta é a opção mais rápida se queremos validar se uma `string` está vazia (sem caracteres) ou não, mas que não é a mais segura, visto que caso a `string` tenha valor `null` originará uma exceção de `System.NullReferenceException`.

Caso tenhamos a certeza absolute que a `string` não será **nunca** `null`, então será uma boa opção.

### Conclusão

Cada caso é um caso, e tudo depende do contexto.

A forma mais segura será, com certeza, utilizar `IsNullOrEmpty` quando não sabemos se o conteúdo será nulo ou não, e mal por mal mais vale prevenir, mas... é preciso avaliar qual das opções, tendo em conta o que temos, será mais viável para uso.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta e atenção!

Answer (score 4):

Um jeito de entender o desempenho é testando:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string test = StrintToTest();

        while(true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key. ESC to exit");
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape) break;

            Console.WriteLine(ElapsedTime("==", () => (test == "")));
            Console.WriteLine(ElapsedTime("Length", () => (test.Length == 0)));
            Console.WriteLine(ElapsedTime("IsNullOrEmpty", () => (string.IsNullOrEmpty(test))));
            Console.WriteLine(ElapsedTime("null or Len", () => (test == null || test.Length == 0)));
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }

    public static string ElapsedTime(string what, Func<bool> method)
    {
        var time = new Stopwatch();

        time.Start();
        long i = 0;
        long total = 1000000;
        while (i++ < total)
            method.Invoke();
        time.Stop();

        return string.Format("{0,15} - Elapsed {1,9:f5} ms", what, time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    public static string StrintToTest()
    {
        return "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
    }
}
```

Na minha máquina o resultado foi:

```
             == - Elapsed   7,48910 ms
         Length - Elapsed   6,62160 ms
  IsNullOrEmpty - Elapsed   5,81710 ms
    null or Len - Elapsed   7,22380 ms
```

Parece justo que checar o tamanho seja mais eficiente do que comparar duas strings.

Chamar o método `IsNullOrEmpty` da classe `string` levou menos tempo do que os outros **nesse teste**. Ao investigar [o código fonte do Framework .Net para o método `IsNullOrEmpty`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,792) temos o seguinte:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(String value) {
    return (value == null || value.Length == 0);
}
```

Então parece haver alguma otimização do compilador quando você utiliza o método da classe `string`. Será?

A questão do desempenho, você precisa fazer os testes para escolher o que for melhor, porém entenda que desempenho é muito relativo. A execução de um código deve considerar muitos fatores do ambiente de execução que você não controla e a maior parte das aplicações não tem a necessidade de otimização de desempenho nesse nível de instruções.

O que sobra então são questões que tem mais a ver com a organização do programa/código. O "código limpo", "código legível", "código organizado" ou o código que segue algum tipo de padrão ou estilo. Isso é o que a gente acaba chamando de código escrito com boas práticas.

Entrando na opinião pessoal, eu lembro que no passado, sempre que a gente entrava num time de desenvolvimento procurava "o guia de boas práticas". Na verdade esse guia era mais direcionado para que o código ficasse de uma certa forma padronizado porque as pessoas tem várias experiências diferentes em vários lugares e acabava que cada um escrevia o código de forma diferente. Não era uma questão do código ser bom ou ruim, rápido ou lento, era uma questão do código ser entendido mais rapidamente por qualquer pessoa da equipe. Se o seu time pode ter esse privilégio, eu não vejo como isso possa atrapalhar ou ser ruim, então antes de seguir as boas práticas, talvez seja necessário entender o que significam as boas práticas naquela comunidade/time que você está inserido.

Comment: O seu teste testa mais a infraestrutura do *delegate* do que qualquer outra coisa.

Comment: "Existem várias formas de preparar Neston. Invente a sua."

Comment: O que isso tem a ver?

Comment: Não conhece a propaganda?

Comment: O que isso tem a ver?

Comment: Tem a ver com o fato de que o código está comparando tempos e você achou exagerado eu usar um recurso que não tem nada a ver com o propósito do teste. Mas eu acho que é apenas outra forma de fazer e é valido. A frase incentiva as pessoas a fazerem uma mesma coisa de formas diferentes.

Comment: Então coloca para fazer uma fatorial de um número grande junto, já que o que está testando não importa. Fazer errado não é válido, agora piorou porque está dizendo que fazer algo sem critério, sem conhecimento, que não produz o resultado esperado é válido, e não é. Acho que não entendeu o que é inventar, não é isto: https://www.wonderslist.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Shoe-umbrellas-600x400.jpg. Inventar algo que produz um resultado ruim é inventar moda, não inventar útil.

Comment: O que tem a ver um fatorial com a questão da checagem da string?

Comment: Agora você está começando entender, o que tem a ver testar a performance de uma *delegate* com testar uma comparação simples? Você está defendendo que isto é válido.

Comment: Eu uso a mesma caixa preta pra testar 4 coisas diferentes. Por que para você importa o que tem na caixa preta se o tempo perdido dentro da caixa preta é igual para qualquer input que ela receba?

Comment: Importa porque ela toma tempo e não é pouco e você está testando tempo, então distorce os resultados, você está testando o tempo do *delegate*, se vai por outras coisas junto, então coloque o fatorial também, segundo o que está dizendo agora não faz diferença.

Comment: Sim, toma tempo, mas a questão aqui é comparação e não medir o tempo absoluto de uma instrução.

Comment: Se o *delegate* toma 10 de tempo (seja á o que for esse 10) e a comparação toma 1 em um caso e 2 no segundo, você terá resultado 11 e 12 e parece quase igual, mas se tirar o tempo do *delegate* é o dobro do tempo no que quer comparar de fato.

Comment: Continua sendo válido porque eu não estou querendo saber se é o dobro ou o triplo, só que saber se é maior ou menor. Para amenizar essas diferenças entre as chamadas é que o código é executado 1.000.000 de vezes.

Comment: Eu desisto, quer fazer errado faça.

Comment: O que você está dizendo é que uma medida muito grande interfere numa medida muito pequena e eu entendo essa parte da estatística, mas não é o caso aqui porque eu não estou fazendo estudo quantitativo e sim comparativo. Eu também coloquei na resposta que desempenho em nível de instrução é bastante relativo e grifei a palavra **nesse teste** para não haver dúvida quanto a resposta. Acho que isso é suficiente.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quiser avaliar se uma string possui valor, o C# possui uma função do próprio tipo primitivo `string`.

Ex:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty("abc");
```

Se você quiser avaliar se uma string possui valor, abstraindo espaços em branco, o C# possui uma função do próprio tipo primitivo `string`.

Ex:

```
string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace("abc");
```

Independente da linguagem, você pode avaliar:

```
var mstr= ''; if(mstr == null) return true;
```

E o resultando será false.