# Por que alguns métodos da string são estáticos?

Tags: c#, .net, string

Estou aprendendo C# depois de já trabalhar com outras linguagens, notei que alguns métodos precisam ser chamados pela classe

```
string.Concat("123","456")
```

Eu costumo usar em outras linguagens desta forma

```
"123".Concat("456")
```

Por que não pode?

Tem jeito de fazer desta forma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O motivo exato só o pessoal que desenvolveu sabe, existem algumas versões.

Há quem diga que

- o Visual Studio não lidava bem com o Intellisense quando o literal *string* era o objeto. Me parece muito inverossímil, resolver isso seria questão de horas ou dias. Não iriam piorar a biblioteca por causa de uma bobagem dessas. O problema existia mesmo, mas não mudariam a sintaxe que é algo definitiva por uma bobagem assim.
- é porque ele está manipulando os dois textos para gerar um novo e não manipulando um deles. Parece sensato, mas aí todos os métodos de `string` deveriam ser estáticos porque a *string* é imutável e ele nunca manipula diferente o objeto. Mas é uma boa teoria.
- fizeram o que o Java fez. Na correria para lançar a tempo pode ter ocorrido mesmo. Não sei se é simplesmente isso, mas podem ter adotado o que já funcionava para não gastar mais tempo pensando nisso. Mas ainda acho que pensaram e a escolha foi pelo motivo anterior.
- o método estático permite concatenar um nulo inicialmente, o que seria impossível com o método de instância, e esse comportamento é desejável. Claro que ninguém concatenará um literal nulo, mas isso foi pensado para uso de variáveis nulas, obviamente que não faria sentido ter o método de um jeito para o literal e outro para a variável ou expressão. Talvez junto com a segunda hipótese seja a razão mais plausível. Mas com o advento das *nullable references* isso será menos usado, se elas existissem desde o início faria menos sentido ter essa forma.
- para deixar mais confortável para quem vem de C ou C++, além do Java, mas acho pouco provável. Eles não tiveram dúvidas em mudar outras coisas. No máximo, consideraram que isso era um bônus.

Design de linguagem é algo extremamente complexo, a quantidade de combinações possível é incrivelmente grande e é fácil esquecer de algum detalhes. Eu posso ter esquecido de algum, ou até desconhecer algo da especificação da linguagem que exigiu algo assim, não por causa deste mecanismo em si, mas por algo não relacionado que não é ortogonal.

## Solução

Acho que a melhor forma de solucionar isso é criando um método de extensão. Mas além dele não funcionar com um nulo gerando uma exceção, portanto precisa ter certeza que não terá um nulo ali, o que faz não ser a solução tão ideal se usa muito isso (a tendência é usar quase nunca com as *nullable references* que agora existe na linguagem), e obrigatoriamente precisa incluir o `System` para que o método de extensão seja chamado. Ou precisa de outro *namespace* se não quiser que o método de extensão esteja sempre disponível para o tipo `string`, mas ficaria mais difícil de usar. [Qual é a diferença de string vs String?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/101)

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        WriteLine("123".Concatenate("456"));
        string.Concat(null, "xxx");
    }
}

namespace System { //isto estaria provavelmente em outro arquivo ou até outro projeto, talvez junto com outros métodos de extensão.
    public static class StringExt {
        public static string Concatenate(this string str1, string str2) => string.Concat(str1, str2);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/dnNMdN). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ar9b5e). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/String/StaticMethod.cs).

Answer (score 0):

Como sabemos, os métodos estáticos, ao contrário dos que são chamados por objetos, são independentes destas instâncias.

No exemplo `"testo".Replace('s','x')` existe um valor a ser modificado, ou seja, é bem cômodo chamar o método pelo objeto.

No caso do método estático Concat(), simplesmente você está livre de uma chamada por um objeto.

Não podemos deixar de notar que o estranho é a existência de métodos não estáticos, pois strings são objetos do tipo referência imutáveis.