# Por que não há método String.ToInt()?

Tags: c#, .net, conversão-de-tipo, objetos

`String` em C# é um objeto, certo? [Pelo que vi](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables) a `string` é uma classe, diferente de `int` e outros tipos primitivos que são tipos simples, (já vi em outro site também, que todos eles são objetos derivados de `System`, então não afirmo com total certeza). A `string` tem alguns métodos como `String.Equals()`, `String.Compare()`, etc, porque não há um método `String.ToInt()` pra substituir o `Int32.Parse()`?
Caso possível uma explicada dos tipos em geral seria legal também.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> String em C# é um objeto, certo?

Todos os tipos são objetos.

> [Pelo que vi](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/types-and-variables?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) a string é uma classe, diferente de `int` e outros tipos primitivos que são tipos simples

`String` é uma classe, portanto um [tipo por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101), porém com [semântica de tipo por valor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101). `Int32` e outros tipos parecidos são por valor, elas são [`structs`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101)s. Em C# não tem essa ideia de tipo primitivo como em Java. [`string` e `int` são apelidos para o tipo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3711/101).

> já vi em outro site também, que todos eles são objetos derivados de `System`, então não afirmo com total certeza

São, tudo acaba sendo derivado de [`Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), [`String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) de forma direta, e [`Int32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) de forma indireta já que é derivado de [`ValueType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetype?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que é derivado de `Object`.

[`System`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0) é um [*namespace*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11199/101), é só um sobrenome para o tipo, não tem relação de herança entre eles, só uma forma de nomear de forma mais organizada.

> A string tem alguns métodos como `String.Equals()`, `String.Compare()`, etc., por que não há um método `String.ToInt()` pra substituir o `Int32.Parse()`?

E por que deveria ter? Cabe a você explicar porque isso seria desejável. O que teria de ganho em ter uma conversão dentro de uma *string* para um inteiro?

`String` é um tipo universal, pode representar qualquer tipo, embora nem todos sejam facilmente representáveis. Todo tipo pode ter uma representação e ela sempre será através de um texto, até mesmo um simples número é mostrado para você como um texto de algarismo(s).

Poucos tipos precisam de uma conversão de *string* para ele. Muitos podem receber uma *string* para compô-lo, mas não uma conversão. Mesmo que todos tipos precisassem cada um teria uma regra diferente de como entender aquele texto e saber que ele é válido e de como deve ser interpretado. Como colocar isto tudo no tipo `String`?

Se ele tiver que ser responsável por toda conversão dele para outros tipos fica inviável. Na verdade, conceitualmente se pensar bem, nenhum tipo deveria ser responsável por qualquer conversão para o seu tipo ou para outro tipo porque haveria uma quantidade enorme de combinações possíveis, e tipos que sequer existem quando você criou um determinado tipo teria que ser adicionados depois sem que o criador do novo tipo tenha acesso ao que se quer converter.

Então a regra básica é que um tipo novo deve ter um tipo auxiliar para conversão ou deve ser responsável pela conversão de tipos já existentes. Um tipo que pode ser considerado universal seria o primeiro de todos.

O mesmo talvez poderia ser dito do `Int32`, ele não deixa de ser um tipo que existe logo no início da linguagem, mas ele não se comunica com todos os tipos de alguma forma, por isso muitos tipos não precisam se converter para ele ou ele se converter dele.

Os tipos numéricos precisam ser convertidos entre si, uma quantidade mais limitada de conversões, então é comum terem a capacidade de fazer isso, em geral implementação a interface [`IConvertible`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iconvertible?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-8.0).

Vamos dizer que você crie um tipo numérico seu, o que fará para trabalhar bem com outros tipos numéricos? Implementará esta interface no seu tipo.

Seu tipo sabe quais são as regras que um texto deve ter para ser compatível com ele. O tipo `String` não sabe, e você não pode mexer no tipo `String`, e não pode herdar dele (esta é outra questão), mas mesmo que pudesse herdar, não deveria herdar para este tipo de coisa. A solução é sempre colocar a conversão de tipos mais universais no seu tipo.

O *framework* optou por seguir a mesma linha que você precisa seguir, é mais intuitivo assim.

Inclusive assim é possível injetar regras específicas que faz sentido para aquele tipo, todos tipos numéricos permitem isto. Se fizesse isto no tipo `String` teria que aceitar regras em geral , não poderia limitar, a não ser que tivesse várias versões do método de conversão que aceitam regras diferentes. Esse tipo seria o mais louco que já se fez.

Qualquer tipo interagir com `String` é fácil de resolver, o `String` interagir com qualquer tipo é difícil.

Note que estamos falando de conversão, mas no fundo é uma interpretação, não é um [`Convert`, é um `Parse`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90981/101).

Aproveito para dizer que este método só pode ser usado se você tem certeza que a interpretação será bem sucedida, se tiver uma chance de estar errada deveria usar o [`TryParse()`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16089/101). Quer que além de um `Parse()` para cada tipo tenha um `TryParse()` também no tipo `String`?

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 0):

Ao definir uma API, você tem que ser o mais genérico possível, principalmente para evitar retrabalho no futuro. Como já existem métodos que fazem essa rotina, se torna desnecessário recolocá-la na classe String. Porém, por praticidade, você pode criar uma extensão:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static int ToInt(this string str)
  {
    return int.Parse(str);
  }
}
```

E utilizá-la assim:

```cs
int i = "1".ToInt();
```