# Estou usando o design pattern Bridge de forma correta?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software, uml

Eu estou estudando padrões de projetos e gostaria de saber se a seguinte abordagem esta correta para o padrão bridge e se tem como melhorar:

[image: Padrão Bridge]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não dá para saber o que deveria ser feito porque não tem na pergunta, mas isso não parece fazer sentido.

As classes das cidades não implementam a interface. Não sei o que `SaoPaulo` está fazendo como agregação ali, a não ser que seja um estado, mesmo assim não consigo ver sentido nisso, `Osasco` não é um detalhe de implementação de SP. E entendo menos ainda porque `Cidadao` herda de `SaoPaulo`. Pra mim nada disso faz sentido. Parece um amontoado de quadrinhos que fazem nada.

Me parece que achou uma solução e agora quer fazer um problema se adaptar a ela. Isto não funciona. Ache o problema e depois procure a melhor solução.

Este padrão existe por uma deficiência da orientação a objeto. Quase todos os padrões classificados pela Gang of Four foram criados para isso. Em uma linguagem funcional não seria tão complicado.

Eu até falo algo sobre isso em [Por que não há método String.ToInt()?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/284845/101).

O padrão permite que uma classe delegue para outras o que fazer. Em vez de herdar uma característica ele permite configurar uma característica no objeto.

Ele permite que o objeto indique qual é o tipo que manipulará algum aspecto daquele objeto. Em geral é feita uma injeção de dependência, então quando for chamado um determinado método desta classe ele chamará o método da classe injetada neste objeto.

[Nessa resposta no SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10689017/221800) tem um bom exemplo:

```
               ----Shape---
              /            \
         Rectangle              Circle
        /         \            /      \
BlueRectangle  RedRectangle BlueCircle RedCircle
```

Fica melhor assim e este é o padrão da ponte:

```
          ----Shape---                        Color
         /            \                       /   \
Rectangle(Color)   Circle(Color)           Blue   Red
```

[image: Padrão Bridge]

Assim evita ter dois níveis de herança que sempre é um complicador e evita ter 4 classes com tudo o que precisa. Você configura a classe de cada forma concreta com a cor que ela deve ter.

Um exemplo em Java retirado [daqui](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/bridge/java/2):

```
class Node {
    public int value;
    public Node prev, next;

    public Node(int i) {
        value = i;
    }
}

class Stack {
    private StackImpl impl;

    public Stack( String s ) {
        if (s.equals("array")) {
            impl = new StackArray();
        } else if (s.equals("list")) {
            impl = new StackList();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Stack: unknown parameter");
        }
    }

    public Stack() {
        this("array");
    }

    public void push(int in) {
        impl.push( in );
    }

    public int pop() {
        return impl.pop();
    }

    public int top() {
        return impl.top();
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return impl.isEmpty();
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return impl.isFull();
    }
}

class StackHanoi extends Stack {
    private int totalRejected = 0;

    public StackHanoi() {
        super("array");
    }

    public StackHanoi(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public int reportRejected() {
        return totalRejected;
    }

    public void push(int in) {
        if (!isEmpty() && in > top()) {
            totalRejected++;
        }
        else {
            super.push(in);
        }
    }
}

class StackFIFO extends Stack {
    private StackImpl stackImpl = new StackList();

    public StackFIFO() {
        super("array");
    }

    public StackFIFO(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    public int pop() {
        while (!isEmpty()) {
            stackImpl.push(super.pop());
        }
        int ret = stackImpl.pop();
        while (!stackImpl.isEmpty()) {
            push(stackImpl.pop());
        }
        return ret;
    }
}

interface StackImpl {
    void push(int i);
    int pop();
    int top();
    boolean isEmpty();
    boolean isFull();
}

class StackArray implements StackImpl {
    private int[] items;
    private int total = -1;

    public StackArray() {
        this.items = new int[12];
    }

    public StackArray(int cells) {
        this.items = new int[cells];
    }

    public void push(int i) {
        if (!isFull()) {
            items[++total] = i;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return total == -1;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return total == items.length - 1;
    }

    public int top() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return items[total];
    }

    public int pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return items[total--];
    }
}

class StackList implements StackImpl {
    private Node last;

    public void push(int i) {
        if (last == null) {
            last = new Node(i);
        } else {
            last.next = new Node(i);
            last.next.prev = last;
            last = last.next;
        }
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return last == null;
    }

    public boolean isFull() {
        return false;
    }

    public int top() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        return last.value;
    }

    public int pop() {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return -1;
        }
        int ret = last.value;
        last = last.prev;
        return ret;
    }
}

public class BridgeDisk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stack[] stacks = {new Stack("array"), new Stack("list"),
                new StackFIFO(), new StackHanoi()};
        for (int i=1, num; i < 15; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < 3; j++) {
                stacks[j].push( i );
            }
        }
        Random rn = new Random();
        for (int i=1, num; i < 15; i++) {
            stacks[3].push(rn.nextInt(20));
        }
        for (int i=0, num; i < stacks.length; i++) {
            while (!stacks[i].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print(stacks[i].pop() + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("total rejected is " + ((StackHanoi)stacks[3]).reportRejected());
    }
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/OOP/Bridge.java).

[Veja outro exemplo](http://www.oodesign.com/bridge-pattern-object-persistence-api-example-java-sourcecode.html).

Ele é como o padrão [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern), mas precisa ser desenvolvido pensando nesta adaptação enquanto que o Adapter pode ser usado mesmo em classes que não foram pensadas para isto.

Ele é "idêntico" ao padrão [Strategy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), exceto pelo fato que esse último é sobre o comportamento e o Bridge é sobre a estrutura do objeto.

Na verdade boa parte dos padrões definidos pelo [Gang of Four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) são muito parecidos quando no mesmo grupo.

Comment: Foi bem clara a resposta. Como eu disse na pergunta, estou estudando o padrão mencionado, tentei puxar um exemplo da vida real pois todos os artigos que li é bem semelhante ao seu exemplo ou sobre JDBC. Mesmo assim foi bem claro e adorei saber que os padrões GOF foram criados justamente para suprir uma deficiência da orientação a objeto, vou pesquisar mais sobre.

Comment: Sim, porém na forma feita, não vejo sentido.