# Por que o Visual Studio sugere que simplifique os nomes? - IDE0001 Name can be simplified

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio, estilo-de-codificação

O Visual Studio 2013 sugere simplificações de nomes, como podem ver abaixo:

[image: SS]

A sugestão é:

> **IDE0001 Name can be simplified**  traduzindo : IDE0001 Nome pode ser simplicado

Exemplo:

```
        var obj = new Object(); //Sugere a simplicação do Object para object
        var outroObj = new object(); //Tudo ok

        var teste = String.Empty; //Sugere a simplicação do nome String para string
        string teste2 = string.Empty; //Tudo ok
        String teste3 = string.Empty; //Também sugere a simplicação do nome String para string
```

Sempre vi gente recomendando usar:

```
string MinhaString = String.Empty;
```

Agora a Microsoft recomenda:

```
string MinhaString = string.Empty;
```

Por que essa sugestão? Qual a vantagem?

Comment: Deixarei alguém com maior conhecimento na linguagem responder, mas dá uma olhada nessa questão do SOen, acredito que ajudará a esclarecer um pouco sua dúvida: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 12):

## String.Empty

Primeiro, `String.Empty` é a mesma coisa que `""`. Quem diz que é diferente ou tem vantagens, [não conhece a implementação e está inventando coisas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263257/221800) (até já foi diferente no passado por implementação interna). O que a pessoa pode, é dizer que fica mais legível, mais claro que você quer que uma *string* vazia seja criada aí. Alguns vão dizer que é fácil você olhar para `""` e para `" "` e achar que é a mesma coisa. Isto eu posso compreender. Ainda que acho exagero.

## Seleção de regras no Visual Studio

Você deve saber que estas informações podem ser desligadas seletivamente, né? Se você não gostar de alguma regra e não quer segui-la, desligue. Se desejar alguma própria, é possível adicioná-la ao sistema de análise de código do VS.

## Regra de nomes

Não há diferença e é apenas uma decisão que deve-se tomar para evitar cada um fazer do seu jeito. Por isto a regra existe.

Nunca consegui encontrar um motivo para escolher claramente um sobre o outro. Como a linguagem preferiu ter um *alias* para a classe da BCL, prefere-se usar ela. Pena que nem a Microsoft a segue em seus códigos :)

## Uso de nomes das classes

Há a recomendação para usar os nomes das classes quando alguma classe ou membro de classe precisa levar o nome do tipo. Exemplo: é melhor `PrintInt32` e não `Print_int` ou pior, `Printint`. Assim fica fácil para outras linguagens que rodam em cima da CLR entenderem ao que se refere já que o `int` é algo exclusivo do C# e não da plataforma (mas eu já não compro tanto isto). `Int32` é o nome do tipo por toda [CLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Infrastructure). Isto vale para todos os [alias de tipos da linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3255/101).

Em nomes de variáveis locais ou mesmo privadas não é problema (pode ser problema em caso de reflexão, mas é raro ser) e é preferível usar o nome descrito pela linguagem. Em expressões, como no exemplo da pergunta, que é algo que não vaza para uso em outras linguagens, a opção é pela forma da linguagem.

Alguns poderão achar que seria mais consistente usar só o nome das classes já que há casos que ele é melhor. Faz sentido, mas a opção foi feita lá atrás para facilitar para quem vem do C/C++/Java.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Eu, sinceramente, penso que os _aliases_ atrapalham mais do que ajudam.

Comment: @Patrick pode elaborar?

Comment: Questão de aprendizagem, uma pessoa que nunca viu isso não vai saber a diferença entre `Object` e `object`; além de que, uma porção de vezes, não deixa nada claro o que está por trás do _alias_.

Comment: Ou seja, atrapalha tanto qualquer outra coisa que a pessoa não saiba o que é. Depois que ela sabe, não atrapalha nada. E na verdade a maioria das pessoas não sabem e programam sem problemas.

Answer (score 5):

Visto que `string` é um *alias* (pseudônimo) de `String`, existe apenas uma vantagem: consistência.

A norma é usar os *aliases* de C# (`string`, `int`, `long`, `bool`) em vez dos tipos .NET (`String`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Boolean`)

Answer (score 5):

Para não precisar fazer o uso do "using System;"

Comment: Não deixa de ser uma vantagem mas em geral não há código útil que não use isto.

Comment: @bigown, poxa, tem muita implementação de classe com `get` e `set` que não precisa de `using System;`. Exemplos: DTOs e Entidades.

Comment: @Dherik esses são os poucos que eu falei. Mesmo assim o ganho é mínimo. Garanto que este não foi o motivo que o FxCop avisa isto.

Comment: @bigown, não foi, mas achei interessante citar que tem muitas classes úteis que não precisam do `using System;`.